# Python: convert alphabetically spelled out numbers to numerics?

Tags: python, parsing

I'm looking for a library, service, or code suggestions to turn spelled out numbers and amounts (eg. "thirty five dollars and fifteen cents", "one point five") into numerics ($35.15, 1.5) . Suggestions?

Comment: Almost a duplicate. <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote some code to do this for integers a while ago: http://github.com/ghewgill/text2num

Feel free to fork and hack.

Comment: I understannd this is an old question and the standards were different. However, as it stands, it is a link-only answer. Are you able to extend it to include the main point of the script?