# Pass from literal string numeric to numeric in R

Tags: r, parsing, tidyr, data-cleaning

let's say I have

`list_of_literals <- c('six', 'seven', 'eight' ... )`

and I want to pass to

`list_of_numerics <- c(6, 7, 9 ...)`

I understand that I can map every possible string value to its numeric value, but, let's suppose that I don't have prior knowledge of the values, so mapping will be very inefficient, is there any package that already does this parsing?

Comment: Maybe this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468241/python-convert-alphabetically-spelled-out-numbers-to-numerics

Comment: Seems interesting Andrey, maybe that would be the most efficient approach for this question.

Comment: One option could be `library(english); v1 <- 1:10;  v1[as.character(english(1:10)) %in% list_of_literals]`

Comment: Nice akrun, that's the answer I was looking for. Please answer the question and I will set it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `english`.  Create an initial vector of numbers ('v1'), convert it to `english` and check whether it is `%in%` the 'list_of_literals' to get a logical `vector` and based on that subset the 'v1'

```
library(english)
v1 <- 1:10
v1[as.character(english(1:10)) %in% list_of_literals]
#[1] 6 7 8
```

#### data

```
list_of_literals <- c("six", "seven", "eight")
```