# .NET convert number to string representation (1 to one, 2 to two, etc...)

Tags: .net

Is there a built in method in .NET to convert a number to the string representation of the number?  For example, 1 becomes one, 2 becomes two, etc.

Comment: I guess this is language and technology (not only .NET) independent question.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I've always been a fan of the recursive method

```
  public static string NumberToText( int n)
  {
   if ( n < 0 )
      return "Minus " + NumberToText(-n);
   else if ( n == 0 )
      return "";
   else if ( n <= 19 )
      return new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 
         "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", 
         "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}[n-1] + " ";
   else if ( n <= 99 )
      return new string[] {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", 
         "Eighty", "Ninety"}[n / 10 - 2] + " " + NumberToText(n % 10);
   else if ( n <= 199 )
      return "One Hundred " + NumberToText(n % 100);
   else if ( n <= 999 )
      return NumberToText(n / 100) + "Hundreds " + NumberToText(n % 100);
   else if ( n <= 1999 )
      return "One Thousand " + NumberToText(n % 1000);
   else if ( n <= 999999 )
      return NumberToText(n / 1000) + "Thousands " + NumberToText(n % 1000);
   else if ( n <= 1999999 )
      return "One Million " + NumberToText(n % 1000000);
   else if ( n <= 999999999)
      return NumberToText(n / 1000000) + "Millions " + NumberToText(n % 1000000);
   else if ( n <= 1999999999 )
      return "One Billion " + NumberToText(n % 1000000000);
   else 
      return NumberToText(n / 1000000000) + "Billions " + NumberToText(n % 1000000000);
}
```

[Source](http://www.dotnet2themax.com/blogs/fbalena/PermaLink,guid,cdceca73-08cd-4c15-aef7-0f9c8096e20a.aspx)

Comment: Nicely done, you should modify it at least to receive longs though. +1

Comment: I liked your code as it was easier to follow than balabaster's.  I modified it a bit to account for a single "0" parameter (returns "Zero"), to accept a long rather than an int, and to return Billion instead of Billions, Million instead of Millions, etc.  Good code!

Comment: @Ryan : i understood your solution but can you explain me the second square bracket operator you used when returning a new string ( if n <= 19 ), as i have not used that style before and didn't understand it. Thanks !

Comment: @Neville: It's just an array indexer.

Answer (score 17):

Ah, there may not be a class to do this, but there was a code golf question which I provided a C# example for:

[Code Golf: Number to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776)

However, it's not the easiest to read and it only goes up to decimal.MaxValue, so I've written a new version that will go as high as you need to.

I couldn't find any information regarding values higher than vigintillions, but if you append the values to the thou[] array, you can continue going up as far as you like.  It still doesn't support fractions, but I'm thinking about adding that at some point.

```
    static string NumericStringToWords(string NumericValue)
    {
        if ("0" == NumericValue) return "zero";

        string[] units = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", 
                           "six", "seven", "eight", "nine" };

        string[] teens = { "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "four", "fifteen", 
                           "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };

        string[] tens = { "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", 
                          "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

        string[] thou = { "thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", 
                          "quadrillion", "quintillion", "sextillion", 
                          "septillion", "octillion", "nonillion", "decillion", 
                          "udecillion", "duodecillion", "tredecillion", 
                          "quattuordecillion", "quindecillion", "sexdecillion", 
                          "septendecillion", "octodecillion", "novemdecillion", 
                          "vigintillion" };

        string sign = String.Empty;
        if ("-" == NumericValue.Substring(0, 1))
        {
            sign = "minus ";
            NumericValue = NumericValue.Substring(1);
        }

        int maxLen = thou.Length * 3;
        int actLen = NumericValue.Length;
        if(actLen > maxLen)
            throw new InvalidCastException(String.Format("{0} digit number specified exceeds the maximum length of {1} digits.  To evaluate this number, you must first expand the thou[] array.", actLen, maxLen));

        //Make sure that the value passed in is indeed numeric... we parse the entire string
        //rather than just cast to a numeric type to allow us to handle large number types passed
        //in as a string.  Otherwise, we're limited to the standard data type sizes.
        int n; //We don't care about n, but int.TryParse requires it
        if (!NumericValue.All(c => int.TryParse(c.ToString(), out n)))
            throw new InvalidCastException();

        string fraction = String.Empty;
        if (NumericValue.Contains("."))
        {
            string[] split = NumericValue.Split('.');
            NumericValue = split[0];
            fraction = split[1];
        }

        StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();
        ulong loopCount = 0;

        while (0 < NumericValue.Length)
        {
            int startPos = Math.Max(0, NumericValue.Length - 3);
            string crntBlock = NumericValue.Substring(startPos);
            if (0 < crntBlock.Length)
            {
                //Grab the hundreds tens & units for the current block
                int h = crntBlock.Length > 2 ? int.Parse(crntBlock[crntBlock.Length - 3].ToString()) : 0;
                int t = crntBlock.Length > 1 ? int.Parse(crntBlock[crntBlock.Length - 2].ToString()) : 0;
                int u = crntBlock.Length > 0 ? int.Parse(crntBlock[crntBlock.Length - 1].ToString()) : 0;

                StringBuilder thisBlock = new StringBuilder();

                if (0 < u)
                    thisBlock.Append(1 == t? teens[u - 1] : units[u - 1]);

                if (1 != t)
                {
                    if (1 < t && 0 < u) thisBlock.Insert(0, "-");
                    if (0 < t) thisBlock.Insert(0, tens[t - 1]);
                }

                if (0 < h)
                {
                    if (t > 0 | u > 0) thisBlock.Insert(0, " and ");
                    thisBlock.Insert(0, String.Format("{0} hundred", units[h - 1]));
                }

                //Check to see if we've got any data left and add
                //appropriate word separator ("and" or ",")
                bool MoreLeft = 3 < NumericValue.Length;
                if (MoreLeft && (0 == h) && (0 == loopCount))
                    thisBlock.Insert(0, " and ");
                else if (MoreLeft)
                    thisBlock.Insert(0, String.Format(" {0}, ", thou[loopCount]));

                word.Insert(0, thisBlock);
            }

            //Remove the block we just evaluated from the 
            //input string for the next loop
            NumericValue = NumericValue.Substring(0, startPos);

            loopCount++;
        }
        return word.Insert(0, sign).ToString();
    }
```

I tested it using Decimal.MaxValue appended to itself to generate a large number of:

seven octodecillion, nine hundred and twenty-two septendecillion, eight hundred and sixteen sexdecillion, two hundred and fifty-one quindecillion, four hundred and twenty-six quattuordecillion, four hundred and thirty-three tredecillion, seven hundred and fifty-nine duodecillion, three hundred and fifty-four udecillion, three hundred and ninety-five decillion, thirty-three nonillion, five hundred and seventy-nine octillion, two hundred and twenty-eight septillion, one hundred and sixty-two sextillion, five hundred and four quintillion, two hundred and sixty-four quadrillion, three hundred and thirty-seven trillion, five hundred and ninety-three billion, five hundred and forty-three million, nine hundred and fifty- thousand, three hundred and thirty-five

Comment: @BobTheBuilder: LOL, maybe, but I'm not sure how I'd write most of the fractions.  Do you write them as hundredths, thousandths, or just "point zero five three nine..." or do you write them as actual fractions like three fifths etc.?

Comment: How about .1 = "one tenth", .14 = "fourteen hundredths", .141 = "one hundred forty one thousandths" and so on? =P

Comment: @Neil Williams: Actually, I'm not sure that would work so well on larger numbers or on long fractions as it could make it more confusing to read than using point zero seven nine... etc.

Answer (score 12):

```
public string IntToString(int number)//nobody really uses negative numbers
{
    if(number == 0)
        return "zero";
    else
        if(number == 1)
            return "one";
        .......
        else
            if(number == 2147483647)
                return "two billion one hundred forty seven million four hundred eighty three thousand six hundred forty seven";
}
```

Comment: Didn't I see this on Daily WTF?

Comment: No, but it should be.  What was I thinking with all those else if's.  I should have used a switch.

Comment: I'm tempted to downvote this, but it's so bad that it actually reversed my decision.. +1 for humor sense.

Comment: Late to the party, But the OP didn't ask any recursion or general solution, this indeed solves the OP's question. +1 for rofl :)

Comment: @WPFUser shh. or it will get deleted.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the modified code I used:

```
//Wrapper class for NumberToText(int n) to account for single zero parameter.
public static string ConvertToStringRepresentation(long number)
{
    string result = null;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        result = "Zero";
    }
    else
    {
        result = NumberToText(number);
    }

    return result;
}

//Found at http://www.dotnet2themax.com/blogs/fbalena/PermaLink,guid,cdceca73-08cd-4c15-aef7-0f9c8096e20a.aspx.
//Modifications from original source:
//  Changed parameter type from int to long.
//  Changed labels to be singulars instead of plurals (Billions to Billion, Millions to Million, etc.).
private static string NumberToText(long n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return "Minus " + NumberToText(-n);
    else if (n == 0)
        return "";
    else if (n <= 19)
        return new string[] {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", 
                                "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", 
                                "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}[n - 1] + " ";
    else if (n <= 99)
        return new string[] {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", 
                                "Eighty", "Ninety"}[n / 10 - 2] + " " + NumberToText(n % 10);
    else if (n <= 199)
        return "One Hundred " + NumberToText(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 999)
        return NumberToText(n / 100) + "Hundred " + NumberToText(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 1999)
        return "One Thousand " + NumberToText(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 999999)
        return NumberToText(n / 1000) + "Thousand " + NumberToText(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 1999999)
        return "One Million " + NumberToText(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 999999999)
        return NumberToText(n / 1000000) + "Million " + NumberToText(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 1999999999)
        return "One Billion " + NumberToText(n % 1000000000);
    else
        return NumberToText(n / 1000000000) + "Billion " + NumberToText(n % 1000000000);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This thread was a great help. I like Ryan Emerle's solution the best for its clarity. Here's my version which I think makes the structure clear as day:

```
public static class Number
{
    static string[] first =
    {
        "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
        "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen",
        "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
    };
    static string[] tens =
    {
        "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety",
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Converts the given number to an english sentence.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="n">The number to convert.</param>
    /// <returns>The string representation of the number.</returns>
    public static string ToSentence(int n)
    {
        return n == 0 ? first[n] : Step(n);
    }
    // traverse the number recursively
    public static string Step(int n)
    {
        return n < 0            ? "Minus " + Step(-n):
               n == 0           ? "":
               n <= 19          ? first[n]:
               n <= 99          ? tens[n / 10 - 2] + " " + Step(n % 10):
               n <= 199         ? "One Hundred " + Step(n % 100):
               n <= 999         ? Step(n / 100) + "Hundred " + Step(n % 100):
               n <= 1999        ? "One Thousand " + Step(n % 1000):
               n <= 999999      ? Step(n / 1000) + "Thousand " + Step(n % 1000):
               n <= 1999999     ? "One Million " + Step(n % 1000000):
               n <= 999999999   ? Step(n / 1000000) + "Million " + Step(n % 1000000):
               n <= 1999999999  ? "One Billion " + Step(n % 1000000000):
                                  Step(n / 1000000000) + "Billion " + Step(n % 1000000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for clarity and making the "constants" a static value, as opposed to the other solutions declaring them inline.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Ryan Emerle's solution, this adds dashes at the correct locations, does not include trailing spaces, does not pluralize numbers, and properly handles an input of zero (0):

```
public static string ToText(long n) {
    return _toText(n, true);
}
private static string _toText(long n, bool isFirst = false) {
    string result;
    if(isFirst && n == 0) {
        result = "Zero";
    } else if(n < 0) {
        result = "Negative " + _toText(-n);
    } else if(n == 0) {
        result = "";
    } else if(n <= 9) {
        result = new[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine" }[n - 1] + " ";
    } else if(n <= 19) {
        result = new[] { "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen" }[n - 10] + (isFirst ? null : " ");
    } else if(n <= 99) {
        result = new[] { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety" }[n / 10 - 2] + (n % 10 > 0 ? "-" + _toText(n % 10) : null);
    } else if(n <= 999) {
        result = _toText(n / 100) + "Hundred " + _toText(n % 100);
    } else if(n <= 999999) {
        result = _toText(n / 1000) + "Thousand " + _toText(n % 1000);
    } else if(n <= 999999999) {
        result = _toText(n / 1000000) + "Million " + _toText(n % 1000000);
    } else {
        result = _toText(n / 1000000000) + "Billion " + _toText(n % 1000000000);
    }
    if(isFirst) {
        result = result.Trim();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my refined version of the first answer. I hope it's useful.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts an <see cref="int"/> to its textual representation
/// </summary>
/// <param name="num">
/// The number to convert to text
/// </param>
/// <returns>
/// A textual representation of the given number
/// </returns>
public static string ToText(this int num)
{
    StringBuilder result;

    if (num < 0)
    {
        return string.Format("Minus {0}", ToText(-num));
    }

    if (num == 0)
    {
        return "Zero";
    }

    if (num <= 19)
    {
        var oneToNineteen = new[]
        {
            "One",
            "Two",
            "Three",
            "Four",
            "Five",
            "Six",
            "Seven",
            "Eight",
            "Nine",
            "Ten",
            "Eleven",
            "Twelve",
            "Thirteen",
            "Fourteen",
            "Fifteen",
            "Sixteen",
            "Seventeen",
            "Eighteen",
            "Nineteen"
        };

        return oneToNineteen[num - 1];
    }

    if (num <= 99)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder();

        var multiplesOfTen = new[]
        {
            "Twenty",
            "Thirty",
            "Forty",
            "Fifty",
            "Sixty",
            "Seventy",
            "Eighty",
            "Ninety"
        };

        result.Append(multiplesOfTen[(num / 10) - 2]);

        if (num % 10 != 0)
        {
            result.Append(" ");
            result.Append(ToText(num % 10));
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    if (num == 100)
    {
        return "One Hundred";
    }

    if (num <= 199)
    {
        return string.Format("One Hundred and {0}", ToText(num % 100));
    }

    if (num <= 999)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder((num / 100).ToText());
        result.Append(" Hundred");
        if (num % 100 != 0)
        {
            result.Append(" and ");
            result.Append((num % 100).ToText());
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    if (num <= 999999)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder((num / 1000).ToText());
        result.Append(" Thousand");
        if (num % 1000 != 0)
        {
            switch ((num % 1000) < 100)
            {
                case true:
                    result.Append(" and ");
                    break;
                case false:
                    result.Append(", ");
                    break;
            }

            result.Append((num % 1000).ToText());
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    if (num <= 999999999)
    {
        result = new StringBuilder((num / 1000000).ToText());
        result.Append(" Million");
        if (num % 1000000 != 0)
        {
            switch ((num % 1000000) < 100)
            {
                case true:
                    result.Append(" and ");
                    break;
                case false:
                    result.Append(", ");
                    break;
            }

            result.Append((num % 1000000).ToText());
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }

    result = new StringBuilder((num / 1000000000).ToText());
    result.Append(" Billion");
    if (num % 1000000000 != 0)
    {
        switch ((num % 1000000000) < 100)
        {
            case true:
                result.Append(" and ");
                break;
            case false:
                result.Append(", ");
                break;
        }

        result.Append((num % 1000000000).ToText());
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in solution in `.net`, but there are good libraries around. The best currently is definitely [Humanizr](http://humanizr.net/):

```
Console.WriteLine(794663.ToWords()); // => seven hundred and ninety-four thousand six hundred and sixty-three
```

It also supports ordinal, and roman representations:

```
Console.WriteLine(794663.ToOrdinalWords()); // => seven hundred and ninety-four thousand six hundred and sixty third
Console.WriteLine(794.ToRoman()); // => DCCXCIV
```

---

`Humanizr` also has a wide range of tools regarding `string`, `DateTime`, `TimeSpan` and so forth.

```
Console.WriteLine(794.Seconds().Humanize().Underscore().Hyphenate()); // => 13-minutes
```

Answer (score 1):

*[A conversion from integer to long form English... I could write that ;-)](http://weblogs.asp.net/justin_rogers/archive/2004/06/09/151675.aspx)* is a pretty good article on the topic:

```
using System;

public class NumberToEnglish {
    private static string[] onesMapping =
        new string[] {
            "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
            "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"
        };
    private static string[] tensMapping =
        new string[] {
            "Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"
        };
    private static string[] groupMapping =
        new string[] {
            "Hundred", "Thousand", "Million", "Billion", "Trillion"
        };

    private static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.WriteLine(EnglishFromNumber(long.Parse(args[0])));
    }

    private static string EnglishFromNumber(int number) {
        return EnglishFromNumber((long) number);
    }

    private static string EnglishFromNumber(long number) {
        if ( number == 0 ) {
            return onesMapping[number];
        }

        string sign = "Positive";
        if ( number < 0 ) {
            sign = "Negative";
            number = Math.Abs(number);
        }

        string retVal = null;
        int group = 0;
        while(number > 0) {
            int numberToProcess = (int) (number % 1000);
            number = number / 1000;

            string groupDescription = ProcessGroup(numberToProcess);
            if ( groupDescription != null ) {
                if ( group > 0 ) {
                    retVal = groupMapping[group] + " " + retVal;
                }
                retVal = groupDescription + " " + retVal;
            }

            group++;
        }

        return sign + " " + retVal;
    }

    private static string ProcessGroup(int number) {
        int tens = number % 100;
        int hundreds = number / 100;

        string retVal = null;
        if ( hundreds > 0 ) {
            retVal = onesMapping[hundreds] + " " + groupMapping[0];
        }
        if ( tens > 0 ) {
            if ( tens < 20 ) {
                retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + onesMapping[tens];
            } else {
                int ones = tens % 10;
                tens = (tens / 10) - 2; // 20's offset

                retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + tensMapping[tens];

                if ( ones > 0 ) {
                    retVal += ((retVal != null) ? " " : "") + onesMapping[ones];
                }
            }
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

Comment: @balabaster: Nor as inclusive as your code golf version, but it *is* easier to read

Comment: @BobTheBuilder: Yeah, but like I said, that's not the purpose of code golf :P

Answer (score 0):

Another naasking, version in VB.NET if any one is interested! Had to use the floor function to round  properly..

```
 Public Function NumberToText(n As Integer) As String
        Dim a As String() = {"One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"}
        Dim tens As String() = {"Twenty", "Thirty", "Forty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy",
         "Eighty", "Ninety"}

        If (n < 0) Then
            Return "Minus " + NumberToText(-n)
        ElseIf (n = 0) Then
            Return ""
        ElseIf (n <= 19) Then
            Return a(n - 1) + " "
        ElseIf (n <= 99) Then
            Return tens(Math.Floor(n / 10) - 2) + " " + NumberToText(n Mod 10)
        ElseIf (n <= 199) Then
            Return "One Hundred " + NumberToText(n Mod 100)
        ElseIf (n <= 999) Then
            Return NumberToText(Math.Floor(n / 100)) + "Hundreds " + NumberToText(n Mod 100)
        ElseIf (n <= 1999) Then
            Return "One Thousand " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000)
        ElseIf (n <= 999999) Then
            Return NumberToText(Math.Floor(n / 1000)) + "Thousands " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000)
        ElseIf (n <= 1999999) Then
            Return "One Million " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000000)
        ElseIf (n <= 999999999) Then
            Return NumberToText(Math.Floor(n / 1000000)) + "Millions " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000000)
        ElseIf (n <= 1999999999) Then
            Return "One Billion " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000000000)
        Else
            Return NumberToText(Math.Floor(n / 1000000000)) + "Billions " + NumberToText(n Mod 1000000000)
        End If

    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete/improved solution based on a couple ideas also posted here. Includes grammar/hyphen fixes, and optional capitalization, long support, support for zero, and yet still very succinct (VB.Net):

```
Function NumberToCapitalizedWords(ByVal n As Long) As String
    Return New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", False).TextInfo.ToTitleCase(NumberToWords(n))
End Function

Function NumberToWords(ByVal n As Long) As String
    Return LTrim(NumberToWords(n, False, False))
End Function

Function NumberToWords(ByVal n As Long, ByVal recursed As Boolean, ByVal iesLast As Boolean) As String
    If (n < 0) Then
        Return "negative" + NumberToWords(-n, False, False)
    ElseIf (n = 0) Then
        If recursed Then
            Return ""
        End If
        Return "zero"
    ElseIf (n < 20) Then
        Return If(iesLast, "-", " ") + New String() {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"}(n - 1)
    ElseIf (n < 100) Then
        Return " " + New String() {"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"}(n \ 10 - 2) + NumberToWords(n Mod 10, True, True)
    ElseIf (n < 1000) Then

        Return NumberToWords(n \ 100, True, False) + " hundred" + NumberToWords(n Mod 100, True, False)
    Else
        Dim log1000 As Integer = Math.Floor(Math.Log(n, 1000))
        Return NumberToWords(n \ PowerNoFloat(1000, log1000), True, False) + " " + New String() {"thousand", "million", "billion", "trillion", "quadrillion", "quintillion"}(log1000 - 1) + NumberToWords(n Mod PowerNoFloat(1000, log1000), True, False)
    End If

End Function

Function PowerNoFloat(ByRef base As Long, ByRef power As Integer) As Long
    If power < 0 Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Dim result As Long = 1
    For i As Integer = 1 To power
        result *= base
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: I added the extra power function because the built in language function returns a double which can cause discrepancies.