# how to use less condition for many condition?

Tags: vb.net

i mean for e.g., numbers are between 1 and 100 .i want to show messagebox for each number as text for example "One" for 1.

is it possible ?
anyone help!

Comment: Have a look at this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a similar program a few years ago. Create a String array with One, Two..Twenty, Thirty, Forty...Hundred

Then with the input number check if <20 just print that array index.

```
if(num < 20)
    print arr[num]
if num>20
    print arr[num/10 + 19] + " " + arr[num%10]
```

I hope you get the drift....