# Method for converting double price value into text

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET convert number to string representation (1 to one, 2 to two, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc)

I need a method which takes double value (ex: 300.5) to a text (ex:Three hundred and fifty)

Comment: I could find something on [The Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15934/How-to-convert-a-numeric-value-or-currency-to-Engl)

Comment: And also on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp) Did you google this?

Comment: extend this for doubles: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3267/284240

Comment: I didn't try anything. I thought that there is a buil-in method for doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into the BCL.

You will need to either find a third party library such as the one @WouterH [commented with](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15934/How-to-convert-a-numeric-value-or-currency-to-Engl), or write your own.