# Using a switch statement to set the value of one particular variable only?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to use a switch statement to set the value of one particular variable used throughout the cases? At the moment if value is 1, I want variable to be 1, and if value is 2, I want variable to be 2.  I am actually doing it simply by:

```
Int variable = value;
```

..however, for future reference where an example is more complex, I wondered if there is a way. (currently getting a variable is already defined error).

```
  switch (value)
        {
            case 0:
                int Variable = 0;
                break;
            case 1:
                int Variable = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                int Variable = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
                int Variable = 3;
                break;
            case 4:
                int Variable = 4;
                break;
        }
```

Comment: All the cases within a `switch` are all in the same scope.  Just put your variable declaration outside of it and assign to it normally.

Comment: Ahh, so obvious now you point it out, I was declaring the variable over and over, thanks alot!

Comment: Are you paid by the number of lines of code you write?

Comment: Seems a bit weird to use 20 lines when 1 works.

Comment: I am using 1 line of code... what are you asking?

Comment: He means why use a switch statement to assign the same value that value contains. Just keep using int Variable = value unless you know that you will eventually assign a different result to Variable. Oh, and read a bit on naming conventions.

Comment: No I meant I wanted to learn how to do it where for example it is more complex such as if I have a string in one variable and want to set another variable to a specific int based on the text, if you know what I mean..(for future reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare your variable outside the swtich, you won't get the "variable already defined" error. This is happening because everything inside the `switch` is in the same scope.

Example:

```
int Variable = -1;

switch (value)
{
        case 0:
            Variable = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            Variable = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            Variable = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
            Variable = 3;
            break;
        case 4:
            Variable = 4;
            break;
}
```

Comment: An `else` clause would be a worthwhile addition to handle any unexpected values.  A possible alternative is to use a nullable type, e.g. `int? Variable;`.

Answer (score 5):

How about a hashtable or dictionary. It's troublesome but quite readable i guess.

Idea taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc).

```
Dictionary<string, int> numbers = new Dictionary<string, int>(){
    {"zero", 0},
    {"one", 1},
    {"two", 2},
    {"three", 3},
    {"four", 4},
    {"five", 5},
    {"size", 6}
};

int Variable = numbers[value];
```