# Why are variables that are declared in one case statement in scope for other cases?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, switch-statement

Why does the following code compile? I would expect that it would complain about `foo` not being declared in the second case branch. Does the compiler handle the declaration such that it's in scope for all cases?

```
using System;

namespace Scratch
{
    class Scratch
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var x = 2;
            switch (x)
            {
                case 1:
                    var foo = "one";
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    foo = "two"; // is foo in scope here?
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: might want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199338/using-a-switch-statement-to-set-the-value-of-one-particular-variable-only

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What @JonSkeet said is correct: A "block" in the C/C++/C# sense is not the same thing as a "case" in the logical sense. But he didn't mention the "best practice" for fixing the issue: If you want to declare a variable inside one case of a switch statement, it's good practice to wrap the whole logical "case" in a block. This way the logical "case" and the actual "scope" recognized by the compiler will be one and the same.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var x = 2;
    switch (x)
    {
        case 1: {  // notice these braces I added
            var foo = "one";
            Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
            foo = "two"; // hooray! foo is no longer in scope here
            Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You beat me to the same response!

Answer (score 9):

> Why does the following code compile?

Because the language is designed in a brain-dead way in this particular area :(

The scope of a local variable is the *block* in which it's declared, and it's accessible at any point lexically after the declaration.

No, I wouldn't design the language that way either. I'm not a fan of the design of switch in C#...

Answer (score 3):

To make it not compile you can scope with the curly braces like this:

```
using System;

namespace Scratch
{
    class Scratch
    {
        public static void Main()
    {
        var x = 2;
        switch (x)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                var foo = "one";
                Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                foo = "two"; // is foo in scope here?
                Console.Out.WriteLine(foo);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This forces that the var foo to only exists within that particular scope.

Answer (score 1):

In C# variables are scoped at block level. As the block follows the switch statement, foo is indeed in scope in both cases.