# .NET or 3rd party library to convert number into "first", "second", "third", etc..."

Tags: c#, .net

As in the title, does anyone know if there's a place in .NET, or a  3rd party library, where integers can be converted to their "ordering" counterparts.

```
1 - first
2 - second
3 - third
etc...
```

I could of course just write one myself, but I'd rather reuse something already existing if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: This is very closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20156/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-ordinals-in-c, and the answers there seem to indicate there is no easy built in way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting numbers in to words C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation)

Comment: Do you have a maximum number?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Humanizer is a great library for this: [Humanizr](https://humanizr.net/)

```
Install-Package Humanizer
```

With Humanizer, you'd do:

```
int number = 5;
string ordinal = number.ToOrdinalWords();
```

Comment: This. I rolled my own library for this, but you will run into language problems pretty fast - the logic how a number is converted to a string differs between languages

Comment: Does this operate in the opposite direction though? -- words -> numbers

Comment: Nope, looks like it doesn't right now. It can convert other humanized things like enums but not number ordinals.

Submit a PR ;-P

Answer (score 1):

[converting numbers in to words C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)

Similiar to this question.  You can get what you need from `LukeH's answer`:

```
public static string NumberToWords(int number)
{
if (number == 0)
    return "zero";

if (number < 0)
    return "minus " + NumberToWords(Math.Abs(number));

string words = "";

if ((number / 1000000) > 0)
{
    words += NumberToWords(number / 1000000) + " million ";
    number %= 1000000;
}

if ((number / 1000) > 0)
{
    words += NumberToWords(number / 1000) + " thousand ";
    number %= 1000;
}

if ((number / 100) > 0)
{
    words += NumberToWords(number / 100) + " hundred ";
    number %= 100;
}

if (number > 0)
{
    if (words != "")
        words += "and ";

    var unitsMap = new[] { "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen" };
    var tensMap = new[] { "zero", "ten", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety" };

    if (number < 20)
        words += unitsMap[number];
    else
    {
        words += tensMap[number / 10];
        if ((number % 10) > 0)
            words += "-" + unitsMap[number % 10];
    }
}

return words;
}
```

Comment: I think you should simply dup it against that question instead of LukeH's answer. Also as noted there it is pretty much en-US only... Other languages/countries would add more fun/complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of a pre-existing library to handle this, but there a great simple method here:
[.NET convert number to string representation (1 to one, 2 to two, etc…)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc)