# Convert Decimal to Text String

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, string-formatting

Trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel if it can be avoided. Is there some special way I have yet to find I can use to convert a currency formatted decimal into the text equivalent?

Best example, when you sign a check and say you put $1,234.56 (StringFormat C) can I grab that value and convert it to "One Thousand Two Hundred Thirty Four & Fifty Six Cents" for checks?

I've looked around and not found anything, was really hoping to not waste a bunch of time if it can be avoided. Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc

Comment: Found this which might help

Here's [a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2729752/converting-numbers-in-to-words-c-sharp)!

Comment: Look at the IBM's ICU [Internationalized Components for Unicode] project at http://site.icu-project.org.

Comment: Excellent! Apparently I should have dumbed down my search to just "Convert number to blah" lol, anyway since this is a duplicate question I'll be deleting it shortly. @Raciel R. thank you as well!

Comment: Ah crap, looks like it wont let me delete it since it had an answer posted, voted to close as duplicate, would like to just delete if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is a good starting point.

http://robertgreiner.com/2011/08/numbertext-converting-numbers-into-words-in-csharp/