# How can I output the hundred and teens numbers in words in my program

Tags: java, methods, do-while

I need help to display my hundred and teens number in words. For example if I enter 116. My program will output One hundred and Six, instead of One hundred and sixteen. All the other numbers that I input work except for the teens numbers.

Comment: Any help that I might receive will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please format your code to use proper indentation. Your snippet is extremely hard to follow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change **4** things in your code:

**First:**

Use `int` instead of `double` for your input

```
int numInput = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());//user inputs number
```

**Second:**

In order to get the appropriate digit placements in `int` use:

```
int hundredsDigit = (numInput % 1000) / 100;
int tensDigit = (numInput % 100) / 10;
int onesDigit = numInput % 10;
```

instead of:

```
double hundredsDigit=Math.floor((numInput%1000)/100);
double tensDigit = Math.floor((numInput % 100) / 10);
double onesDigit = numInput % 10;
```

**Third:**

The `else` condition for the 110-119 range must be before the 100-999 (which technically should be 120-999)

**Fourth:**

Your teens method is taking the original numInput as parameter.

What you need to take is the `onesDigit` to determine which "teen" it is

So it should be a call like:

```
teens(onesDigit);
```

This call **must** be changed in the [10-19] condition and the [110-119] condition

And your teens new method should look like:

```
public static void teens(int onesDigit) {
    if (onesDigit == 0) {
        System.out.print("Ten ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 1) {
        System.out.print("Eleven ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 2) {
        System.out.print("Twelve ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 3) {
        System.out.print("Thirteen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 4) {
        System.out.print("Fourteen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 5) {
        System.out.print("Fifteen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 6) {
        System.out.print("Sixteen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 7) {
        System.out.print("Seventeen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 8) {
        System.out.print("Eighteen ");
    }
    if (onesDigit == 9) {
        System.out.print("Nineteen ");
    }
}//closes teens method
```

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you check if the number is in the range [100, 999] before checking that it is in the range [100, 119], change the order of the ifs and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you wan't this, **[I did not write this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794831/1768238)**:

```
public static String intToText(int n) {
    if (n < 0)
        return "Minus " + intToText(-n);
    else if (n == 0)
        return "Zero";
    else if (n <= 19)
        return oneToNineteen[n - 1] + " ";
    else if (n <= 99)
        return twentyToNinety[n / 10 - 2] + " " + intToText(n % 10);
    else if (n <= 199)
        return "One Hundred " + intToText(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 999)
        return intToText(n / 100) + "Hundred " + intToText(n % 100);
    else if (n <= 1999)
        return "One Thousand " + intToText(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 999999)
        return intToText(n / 1000) + "Thousand " + intToText(n % 1000);
    else if (n <= 1999999)
        return "One Million " + intToText(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 999999999)
        return intToText(n / 1000000) + "Million " + intToText(n % 1000000);
    else if (n <= 1999999999)
        return "One Billion " + intToText(n % 1000000000);
    else
        return intToText(n / 1000000000) + "Billion " + intToText(n % 1000000000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Start from smallest number to highest when comparing.

First condition:

```
if((numInput>=10)&&(numInput<=19)){
```

Second:

```
else if((numInput>=20)&&(numInput<=99)){
```

Third:

```
else if((numInput>100)&&(numInput<=119)){
```

Fourth:

```
else if((numInput>=100)&&(numInput<=999)){
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the

```
else if((numInput>100)&&(numInput<=119))
```

clause before the more inclusive

```
else if((numInput>=100)&&(numInput<=999))
```

What's happening here is that the larger range is searched first, and your `tens` function doesn't output anything for `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your else if

```
else if((numInput>100)&&(numInput<=119)){
        hundreds(hundredsDigit);
        System.out.print(" ");
        teens(numInput);
    }
```

must be placed one level higher... Since the

```
else if((numInput>=100)&&(numInput<=999)){
        hundreds(hundredsDigit);
        System.out.print(" ");
        tens(tensDigit);
        System.out.print(" ");
        ones(onesDigit);

    }
```

will also fulfill the condition, the "116" you entered will never get there...

Answer (score 0):

This was fun.  It has the following issues:

-Only deals with integers.  No longs, doubles etc.
-Doesn't deal with the single case of zero.
-Fails at Integer.MIN_VALUE because of the number = number * -1

Otherwise, it seems to work.  The motivation was that I can't stand huge blocks of "if-else" code.

```
public class NumbersToWords {
    private static final Map<Integer,String> NUM_TO_WORD = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static final List<Integer> KEYS = new ArrayList<Integer>(30);

    static {
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(0,"zero");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(1,"one");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(2,"two");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(3,"three");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(4,"four");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(5,"five");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(6,"six");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(7,"seven");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(8,"eight");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(9,"nine");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(10,"ten");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(11,"eleven");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(12,"twelve");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(13,"thirteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(14,"fourteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(15,"fifteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(16,"sixteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(17,"seventeen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(18,"eighteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(19,"nineteen");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(20,"twenty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(30,"thirty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(40,"forty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(50,"fifty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(60,"sixty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(70,"seventy");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(80,"eighty");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(90,"ninety");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(100,"hundred");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(1000,"thousand");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(1000000,"million");
        NUM_TO_WORD.put(1000000000,"billion");

        KEYS.addAll(NUM_TO_WORD.keySet());

        Collections.sort(KEYS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] testValues = {24,4,543755,12,10000,123000,123,Integer.MAX_VALUE, -456};
        NumbersToWords ntw = new NumbersToWords();
        for(int i : testValues){
            System.out.println(i + " -> " + ntw.getWords(i));
        }
    }

            /* called recursively */
    public String getWords(int number){
        boolean isNegative = number < 0;
        if(isNegative){
            number = number * -1;
        }

        if(number < 100){
            return getWordLessThanHundred(number);
        }

        StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder(50);
        int key = getKey(number);
        if(isNegative){
            words.append("negative ");
        }
        words.append(getWords(number/key)) 
             .append(" ").append(NUM_TO_WORD.get(key)) // get the largest placeholder word
             .append(" ").append(getWords(number % key)); // get the rest
        return words.toString();
    }

    private String getWordLessThanHundred(int number){
        if(number == 0){
            return "";
        }

        if(number < 21){
            return NUM_TO_WORD.get(number);
        }

        int key = getKey(number);
        return NUM_TO_WORD.get(key) + " " + NUM_TO_WORD.get(number - key);
    }

    private int getKey(int number){
       for(int i = 0; i<KEYS.size();i++){
           int value = KEYS.get(i);
           if(i > 0 && number < value){
               return KEYS.get(i - 1);
           }else if(number == value){
               return value;
           }
       }
       return KEYS.get(KEYS.size() - 1);
    }   
}
```