# Enter number in one textbox and get word as output in another textbox

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

This Question was asked in interview but i was unable to answer it
please any one can tell me how to do this ?

i have two textboxs txtInput and  txtOutput

When user clicks the btnSubmit, he should get the number written in txtInput in words in txtOutput. Eg. if user enters 100 in txtInput, he should get hundred in txtOutput

Comment: I think you need to google this and find the solution. here is one [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33282/Simple-Class-to-Convert-Numbers-into-Text) which I found. may be it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks ..found solution here

[.NET convert number to string representation (1 to one, 2 to two, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc)

Answer (score 0):

Prumably this is JS. If it is the you can setup an event listener on the submit button and disable the default behavior. Pass the input value to a function that builds the number string and update the dom element for the output textbox with that return result.

If you're using a round trip to the server for the calculation then just ignore all the dom stuff and return the page with the appropriate values set.

If you're using a front end framework then this gets easier but more specific to the framework.