# How to convert numerical value to words?

Tags: c#

Hey anyone know about a function in C# that converts numerical value in to words
Like If I give Input: 53904
Then the output should be: FIFTY THREE THOUSAND NINE HUNDRED FOUR ONLY

Comment: First lets try somthing man

Comment: have a look on this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc

Comment: @Robin no tags in titles, please.

Comment: There are two duplicate questions(!!!), and one among them should also have to be locked. And why its not?

Answer (score 6):

By far, the best solution for this is the [.NET Humanizr](http://humanizr.net/). It installs a series of extension methods and you can use it just like this:

```
15.ToWords(); // Returns "Fifteen"

int i;
i = 1587;
i.ToWords(); // Returns "One Thousand Five Hundred and Eighty Seven"
```

This works not only for numbers, but it works on DateTime, TimeSpan, Enums and others. I have used it in one of projects and it works great!

In addition, it has several other language translations, so it'll work in other languages, if you need it to.