# how to convert number to words (Money Format) using PowerShell?

Tags: .net, powershell

I want the PowerShell script to convert numbers like "52" as "Fifty Two".

Comment: Cool, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682437/powershell-is-there-an-easy-way-to-covert-an-int-5-to-a-string-five-or-68-to-six

Comment: Thanks for your Responses. and @Blake Thanks for your suggestion. I want the same thing in the PowerShell script. well, I will try it now. Thank you, Guys.