# Powershell replace only numbers in beginning of string

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a lot of strings that I am going to loop through and be changing various characters in. One thing I need to do is convert numbers at the beginning of the string to their string representation. Example: `'10_hello_1'` to `'ten_hello_1'`. There will always be a '_' after a number. I have tried various things such as: `$a.replace('\d{2}_','')` (just to at least delete the beginning numbers) but that does not work.

I have even thought of breaking this down further and using a '$a.startswith()` clause but can not get powershell to ask "does this start with any arbitrary number".

I have found a lot about string manipulation on the web I just can't piece it altogether. Thanks!

Comment: What is exact thing you want to help with? Writing function to convert from number to text? Checking if string starts with digits, and replacing that digits?

Comment: checking if a string starts with digits and replacing digits. The digits could be any number of characters long followed by a '_' character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string .Replace method does not use regular expressions. Instead use the -Replace operator:

```
$a = '10_hello_1'
$a -replace '^\d+', ''
```

As for getting a word conversion of a number, I'm not aware of any built in method. Here is a question that proposes a .Net way to do it that you could easily convert to Powershell:

[.NET convert number to string representation (1 to one, 2 to two, etc...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/794663/net-convert-number-to-string-representation-1-to-one-2-to-two-etc)

Comment: Oh... Is there a general way to identify what does and does not work with regular expressions?

Comment: I don't know of any way off the top of my head. I just look at the documentation.

Comment: Edited to cause the regex to replace all starting numerals rather than just the two digits asked for in the question.

Answer (score 2):

EBGreen is perfectly correct as to why you are having an issue. I would like to offer a less error prone solution though.

```
$a -replace '^\d+_'
```

That would replace *all* numbers up to and including an underscore at the *beginning* of the string.