# converting the numerals as string

Tags: vb.net

Can someone help mo on how to convert a number value to its string value
(ie.,1198.00 should be interpreted as Thousand Hundred and ninety eight)

Comment: Is this homework? It helps if you mark it as such, we then know how to help (i.e. to give more of a teaching answer rather than just "lol here is teh codes").

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting a decimal to an English string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018548/converting-a-decimal-to-an-english-string)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in - you will need to write your own.

Here is [one way](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=8704) of doing it, and a quick search finds [several](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/NumToWord.aspx) [other](http://www.demtron.com/blog/post/2009/02/02/VBNet-Converting-Number-to-Words.aspx) [samples](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/afc4ffcf-f9b2-4bdb-8324-23ed3b456112/vb--numeric-to-word-conv.aspx) to look at.

As a note - all of these approaches suffer from being tied to a single language, so non of them can be used as is for internationalization/localization efforts.