# Why aren't programs written in Assembly more often?

Tags: c, programming-languages, assembly

It seems to be a mainstream opinion that assembly programming takes longer and is more difficult to program in than a higher level language such as C. Therefore it seems to be recommend or assumed that it is better to write in a higher level language for these reasons and for the reason of better portability.

Recently I've been writing in x86 assembly and it has dawned on me that perhaps these reasons are not really true, except perhaps portability. Perhaps it is more of a matter of familiarity and knowing how to write assembly well. I also noticed that programming in assembly is quite different than programming in an HLL. Perhaps a good and experienced assembly programmer could write programs just as easily and as quickly as an experienced C programmer writing in C.

Perhaps it is because assembly programming is quite different than HLLs, and so requires different thinking, methods and ways, which makes it seem very awkward to program in for the unfamiliar, and so gives it its bad name for writing programs in.

If portability isn't an issue, then really, what would C have over a good assembler such as NASM?

**Edit:**
Just to point out. When you are writing in assembly, you don't have to write just in instruction codes. You can use macros and procedures and your own conventions to make various abstractions to make programs more modular, more maintainable and easier to read. This is where being familiar with how to write good assembly comes in.

Comment: Write ? What about reading code ? you (and others) will read the code a lot lot more than you write it

Comment: Why should I have to learn a new language just because my program shall run on a new platform? Why should I have to construct my programs to fit the CPUs idea of how many registers there are and what you can do with it? I try to solve problems, not do the computers bidding.

Comment: Well, I have yet to see the boost lib of assembly programming. Or the .NET framework. Or the wxWindows. Or...

Comment: You might find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019313/what-kind-of-projects-besides-the-obvious-os-stuff-use-assembly-language

Comment: And you might find this interesting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791533/why-do-you-program-in-assembly

Comment: @M28: easy, because no one came up with a high-performance brainf*** compiler and/or virtual machine yet.

Comment: Assembler is still a valid and useful thing to know.  Imagine trying to debug an optimized build without any knowledge of assembly...

Comment: Summary of the EDIT: One can use a C compiler.

Comment: The reality is that the optimizers in C are so good know that they exceed the average assembler programmer in efficiency. Since most of us are probably average assembler programmers C will create faster code.

Comment: @matt b - Really? In 1980 I and many others were writing programs in Assembly. No-one, that I know of, would have been asking why there weren't more people doing it. There were already loads doing it.

Comment: @Simon Maybe I have my years wrong then, but I am surprised that we are debating ASM vs "a high-level language like C" in 2010. Specifically the part where C is the example of a high-level language

Comment: Little bit out-of-date but: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9601625/1207195

Comment: @changelog: That's not how you spell programming.reddit.com.

Comment: 8-bit PICs see a lot of ASM love and for good reason...

Answer (score 331, accepted):

ASM has **poor legibility** and **isn't really maintainable** compared to higher-level languages.

Also, there are many **fewer ASM developers** than for other more popular languages, such as C.

Furthermore, if you use a higher-level language and **new ASM instructions become available** (SSE for example), you just need to update your compiler and your old code can easily make use of the new instructions.

What if the next CPU has twice as many registers?

The converse of this question would be: *What functionality do compilers provide?*

I doubt you can/want to/should optimize your ASM better than `gcc -O3` can.

Comment: gcc is not that great at optimization, far better than the average human, but there are many places where the optimizers fail to do a good job.  Agree with you though otherwise.

Comment: @dwelch It is in very rare instances that gcc (or many other compilers) fail to properly optimize compiled C. In those instances, however, you can always write a limited number of procedures in ASM and link just those methods in during build.

Comment: It is not rare I see it every program compiled.  that doesnt mean it should be fixed in every program. I agree you need a really good reason and if so then call a tuned routine.  If you dont live in an corner case world like the one I work in I would say you should probably never touch or tune the compilers output other than using compiler switches.  There are far better compilers than gcc where I would lean even more to agreeing with you completely.

Comment: There are many cases where a compiler cannot optimize well, but quite often a developer that is aware of limitations of the optimizer can optimize his C code without resorting to assembly.

Comment: FWIW in my day job I compile our product with gcc -g -O0, because being able to attach gdb to it on a live system and not go mad due to variables optimized out of existence, is worth a hell of a lot more to the company than it would be to leave another 4 billion CPU cycles idle every day (out of a total of 3 trillion).  Crunching integers just isn't the bottleneck very often.

Comment: "new ASM instructions become available (SSE for example)" Nah you don't you have to use intrinsic functions if you want to make sure that your code really uses SSE properly.

Comment: "there are many fewer ASM developers" is a bit of a circular argument.

Comment: Article about GCC optimization - http://lwn.net/Articles/534735/

Comment: gcc can sometimes only make good code with hints like "__restrict__". The compiler has to be conservative about aliasing and can mess up various things due to lack of knowledge about the actual way the code will be used. I think the "compiler will do a far better job than most humans" is generally a myth.

Answer (score 1929):

Hellо, I am a compiler.

I just scanned thousands of lines of code while you were reading this sentence. I browsed through millions of possibilities of optimizing a single line of yours using hundreds of different optimization techniques based on a vast amount of academic research that you would spend years getting at. I won't feel any embarrassment, not even a slight ick, when I convert a three-line loop to thousands of instructions just to make it faster. I have no shame to go to great lengths of optimization or to do the dirtiest tricks. And if you don't want me to, maybe for a day or two, I'll behave and do it the way you like. I can transform the methods I'm using whenever you want, without even changing a single line of your code. I can even show you how your code would look in assembly, on different processor architectures and different operating systems and in different assembly conventions if you'd like. Yes, all in seconds. Because, you know, I can; and you know, you can't.

P.S. Oh, by the way you weren't using half of the code you wrote. I did you a favor and threw it away.

Answer (score 99):

I've written shedloads of assembler for the 6502, Z80, 6809 and 8086 chips. I stopped doing so as soon as C compilers became available for the platforms I was addressing, and immediately became at least 10x more productive. Most good  programmers use the tools they use for rational reasons.

Answer (score 72):

I love programming in assembly language, but it takes more code to do the same thing as in a high-level languge, and there is a direct correlation between lines of code and bugs. (This was explained decades ago in [The Mythical Man-Month](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month).)

It's possible to think of C as 'high level assembly', but get a few steps above that and you're in a different world. In C# you don't think twice about writing this:

```
foreach (string s in listOfStrings) { /* do stuff */ }
```

This would be dozens, maybe hundreds of lines of code in assembly, each programmer implementing it would take a different approach, and the next person coming along would have to figure it out. So if you believe (as many do) that programs are written primarily for other people to read, assembly is less readable than the typical HLL.

**Edit:** I accumulated a personal library of code used for common tasks, and macros for implementing C-like control structures. But I hit the wall in the 90s, when GUIs became the norm. Too much time was being spent on things that were routine.

The last task I had where ASM was essential was a few years ago, writing code to combat malware. No user interface, so it was all the fun parts without the bloat.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I seem recall reading in Code Complete that this was not the case...

Comment: I'm sure there's a point where the 'fewer lines' advantage is beaten by the 'premature optimization' disadvantage. But I haven't looked at Code Complete in ages...

Comment: A bit ironic to use "premature optimization" as an argument *for* assembly...  (I probably misinterpret you though.  I still think it's funny.)

Comment: You can still call function in assembler, so I doubt that a foreach-loop takes dozens to hundreds of lines. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @phresnel : `foreach` does far more work than `for` - it instantiates and uses a type-specific iterator.

Comment: 0) I think your last statement is too general: This does that, too: `for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = .....)`. --- 1) This would be my version of `foreach` (pseudo assembly; better copy and reformat in text editor):  `/* init */
declare it, end : iterator; 
call list.begin; 
call it.ctor; 
call list.end; 
call end.ctor; 
$loop_begin: 
   /* condition */
   mov &it, R0; 
   mov &end, R1; 
   call iter_compare; 
   test R0, 0;
   jnz $loop_begin;
   /* body */
   ....
   /* repeat */
   jmp $loop_begin;
$loop_end:` --> that's 13 lines of x86 inspired assembly for a simple `for`-boilerplate.

Answer (score 15):

In addition to other people's answers of readability, maintainability, shorter code and therefore fewer bugs, and being much easier, I'll add an additional reason:

program speed.

Yes, in assembly you can hand tune your code to make use of every last cycle and make it as fast as is physically possible. However who has the time? If you write a not-completely-stupid C program, the compiler will do a really good job of optimizing for you. Probably making at least 95% of the optimizations you'd do by hand, without you having to worry about keeping track of any of it. There's definitely a 90/10 kind of rule here, where that last 5% of optimizations will end up taking up 95% of your time. So why bother?

Comment: +1. Writing assembler code and writing *fast* assembler code are two different things. If you use a good compiler, you get the fast assembler code for free.

Comment: you get fast assembler code for free only if you know how to use the compiler, most do not use optimization, most people compile with debug options and as a result end up with poorly done slow assembler.
yes over 99% of the time you shouldnt touch it, just touch the compilers knobs and not tweak the output directly.

Comment: if you care about the optimizations, then you should be doing that from the compiler... IF you don't care about optimizations, but you're still using assembly, then you're just being silly.

Comment: @dwelch: I guess there might be some script-kiddies who don't bother to find out how they're tools are used. But I doubt people like them would ever be able to write fast assembler code.

Answer (score 13):

If an average production program has say 100k lines of code, and each line is about 8-12 assembler instructions, that would be 1 million of assembler instructions.

Even if you could write all this by hand at a decent speed (remember, its 8 times more code that you have to write), what happens if you want to change some of the functionality? Understanding something you wrote a few weeks ago out of those 1 million instructions is a nightmare! There's no modules, no classes, no object-oriented design, no frameworks, no nothing. And the amount of similar looking code you have to write for even the simplest things is daunting at best.

Besides, you can't optimize your code nearly as well as a high level language. Where C for example performs an insane number of optimizations because you *describe* your intent, not only your code, in assembler you only write code, the assembler can't really perform any note-worthy optimizations on your code. What you write is what you get, and trust me, you can't reliably optimize 1 million instructions that you patch and patch as you write it.

Answer (score 8):

Well I have been writing a lot of assembly "in the old days", and I can assure you that I am much more productive when I write programs in a high level language.

Comment: "Assembly is Latin".

Comment: @Adriano: except there are many, many different dialects and no two of them look alike.

Comment: Sure, but I meant that learning to program in any of them gives you an insight on the architecture of a machine that helps you at higher levels. Unless you deal with paged memory, in that case you end up scarred. Like reading Carmen 16 from Catullus.

Comment: @Adriano "Assembly is Latin", No asm is caveman grunts. One grunt for rock 2grunts for deer, 3grunts for fire - good for simple stuff but hard to run an empire on.

Comment: @Martin: Have you ever tried to do complex arithmetics with Roman numerals?

Comment: @AdrianoVaroliPiazza: You should read the Intel/AMD documentations about optimization and architecture. Assembly does not teach you the architecture, if at all, it gives you a small tool that helps to support your understanding.

Answer (score 6):

A reasonable level of assembler competence is a useful skill, especially if you work at any sort of system level or embedded programming, not so much because you have to write that much assembler, but because sometimes it's important to understand what the box is *really* doing.  If you don't have a low-level understanding of assembler concepts and issues, this can be very difficult.

However, as for actually writing much code in assembler, there are several reasons it's not much done.

- There's simply no (almost) need.  Except for something like the very early system initialization and perhaps a few assembler fragments hidden in C functions or macros, all very low-level code that might once have been written in assembler can be written in C or C++ with no difficulty.
- Code in higher-level languages (even C and C++) condenses functionality into far fewer lines, and there is considerable research showing that the number of bugs correlates with the number of lines of source code.  Ie, the same problem, solved in assembler and C, will have more bugs in assembler simply because its longer.  The same argument motivates the move to higher level languages such as Perl, Python, etc.
- Writing in assembler, you have to deal with every single aspect of the problem, from detailed memory layout, instruction selection, algorithm choices, stack management, etc.  Higher level languages take all this away from you, which is why are so much denser in terms of LOC.

Essentially, all of the above are related to the level of abstraction available to you in assembler versus C or some other language.  Assembler forces you to make all of your own abstractions, and to maintain them through your own self-discipline, where any mid-level language like C, and especially higher level languages, provide you with abstractions out of the box, as well as the ability to create new ones relatively easily.

Answer (score 6):

*When you are writing in assembly, you don't have to write just in instruction codes. You can use macros and procedures and your own conventions to make various abstractions to make programs more modular, more maintainable and easier to read.*

So what you're basically saying is, that with skilled use of a sophisticated assembler, you can make your ASM code closer and closer to C (or anyway another low-ish-level language of your own invention), until eventually you are just as productive as a C programmer.

Does that answer your question? ;-)

I don't say this idly: I have programmed using exactly such an assembler and system. Even better, the assembler could target a virtual processor, and a separate translator compiled the output of the assembler for a target platform. Much as happens with LLVM's IF, but in its early forms pre-dating it by about 10 years. So there was portability, plus the ability to write routines for a specific target asssembler where required for efficiency.

Writing using that assembler was about as productive as C, and with by comparison with GCC-3 (which was around by the time I was involved) the assembler/translator produced code that was roughly as fast and usually smaller. Size was really important, and the company had few programmers and was willing to teach new hires a new language before they could do anything useful. And we had the back-up that people who didn't know the assembler (e.g. customers) could write C and compile it for the same virtual processor, using the same calling convention and so on, so that it interfaced neatly. So it felt like a marginal win.

That was with multiple man-years of work in the bag developing the assembler technology, libraries, and so on. Admittedly much of which went into making it portable, if it had only ever been targeting one architecture then the all-singing all-dancing assembler would have been much easier.

In summary: you may not like C, but it doesn't mean that the effort of using C is greater than the effort of coming up with something better.

Answer (score 6):

As a developer who spends most of his time in the embedded programming world, I would argue that assembly is far from a dead/obsolete language.  There is a certain close-to-the-metal level of coding (for example, in drivers) that sometimes cannot be expressed as accurately or efficiently in a higher-level language.  We write nearly all of our hardware interface routines in assembler.

That being said, this assembly code is wrapped such that it can be called from C code and is treated like a library.  We don't write the entire program in assembly for many reasons.  First and foremost is portability; our code base is used on several products that use different architectures and we want to maximize the amount of code that can be shared between them.  Second is developer familiarity.  Simply put, schools don't teach assembly like they used to, and our developers are far more productive in C than in assembly.  Also, we have a wide variety of "extras" (things like libraries, debuggers, static analysis tools, etc) available for our C code that aren't available for assembly language code.  Even if we wanted to write a pure-assembly program, we would not be able to because several critical hardware libraries are only available as C libs.  In one sense, it's a chicken/egg problem.  People are driven away from assembly because there aren't as many libraries and development/debug tools available for it, but the libs/tools don't exist because not enough people use assembly to warrant the effort creating them.

In the end, there is a time and a place for just about any language.  People use what they are most familiar and productive with.  There will probably always be a place in a programmer's repertoire for assembly, but most programmers will find that they can write code in a higher-level language that is almost as efficient in far less time.

Answer (score 5):

Assembly is not portable between different microprocessors.

Comment: That's not exactly true with modern processors and assembler programs, you can target different processors just as you can in C. Sure you won't be able to use the full set of instructions in this case, but then neither do you if you write it in C. Portability isn't the primary concern.

Comment: Maybe you mean *architecture*.

Comment: @Blindy - You can target different processors within the x86 family but there is definitely no commonality in assembly instructions between an x86 variant and an ARM processor or a Z80 or an 8051.

Comment: True, but then you can't program a z80 in c either. I think we're all talking about normal x86/x64 processors here.

Comment: @Ben S - Thank you for your suggestion.  Perhaps architecture would have been a better choice of words.

Comment: @Blindy:  I did have a C compiler once for a CP/M computer with a Z80.  This was pre-standard, and I don't remember what would have had to be changed to conform to C90, and I don't know how difficult that would have been.

Comment: @Blindy, see sdcc the open source "Small Devices C Compiler" which does target the Zilog Z80 and other small micros.

Comment: All the world is not an x86.  Nothing about "different microprocessors" suggests that they all execute the same instruction set.

Answer (score 5):

The same reason we don't go to the bathroom outside anymore, or why we don't speak Latin or Aramaic.

Technology comes along and makes things easier and more accessible.

EDIT - to cease offending people, I've removed certain words.

Comment: You are still offending Luddites with the word `Technology`

Comment: "We" don't speak Latin?

Comment: Neither Latin nor Aramaic did disappear because they were replaced by better technology (i.e. an easier to learn/pick up language). In fact, Latin is still with us everywhere in Europe. All Roman languages are based on Latin.
Modern (neo) Aramaic is spoken by almost half a million people today.

The reasons these languages are not prevalent any more are historical (geopolitical, to be more precise), not technological. Same reason English is the lingua franca of the science and ruling classes of our age -- the people of the last empire, the British (and now US American) speak it.

Answer (score 4):

Why? Simple.

Compare this :

```
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                Console.Write("Fizz");
            if (i % 5 == 0)
                Console.Write("Buzz");
            if (i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0)
                Console.Write(i);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

with

```
.locals init (
    [0] int32 i)
L_0000: ldc.i4.1 
L_0001: stloc.0 
L_0002: br.s L_003b
L_0004: ldloc.0 
L_0005: ldc.i4.3 
L_0006: rem 
L_0007: brtrue.s L_0013
L_0009: ldstr "Fizz"
L_000e: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
L_0013: ldloc.0 
L_0014: ldc.i4.5 
L_0015: rem 
L_0016: brtrue.s L_0022
L_0018: ldstr "Buzz"
L_001d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(string)
L_0022: ldloc.0 
L_0023: ldc.i4.3 
L_0024: rem 
L_0025: brfalse.s L_0032
L_0027: ldloc.0 
L_0028: ldc.i4.5 
L_0029: rem 
L_002a: brfalse.s L_0032
L_002c: ldloc.0 
L_002d: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::Write(int32)
L_0032: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine()
L_0037: ldloc.0 
L_0038: ldc.i4.1 
L_0039: add 
L_003a: stloc.0 
L_003b: ldloc.0 
L_003c: ldc.i4.s 100
L_003e: ble.s L_0004
L_0040: ret
```

They're identical feature-wise.
The second one isn't even assembler but .NET IL (Intermediary Language, similar to Java's bytecode). The second compilation transforms the IL into native code (i.e. almost assembler), making it even more cryptical.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess ASM on even x86(_64) makes sense in cases where you gain a lot by utilizing instructions that are difficult for a compiler to optimize for. x264 for example uses a lot of asm for its encoding, and the speed gains are huge.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are many reasons, but two quick reasons I can think of are

1. Assembly code is definitely harder to read (I'm positive its more time-consuming to write as well)
2. When you have a huge team of developers working on a product, it is helpful to have your code divided into logical blocks and protected by interfaces.

Comment: Note that you can separate assembly into logical blocks, too.

Answer (score 2):

One of the early discoveries (you'll find it in Brooks' *Mythical Man-Month*, which is from experience in the 1960s) was that people were more or less as productive in one language as another, in debugged lines of code per day.  This obviously isn't universally true, and can breaks when pushed too far, but it was generally true of the high-level languages of Brooks' time.

Therefore, the fastest way to get productivity would be to use languages where one individual line of code did more, and indeed this works, at least for languages of complexity like FORTRAN and COBOL, or to give a more modern example C.

Answer (score 2):

Portability is *always* an issue -- if not now, at least eventually. The programming industry spends billions every year to port old software which, at the time it was written, had "obviously" no portability issue whatsoever.

Comment: "It won't have to port to another architecture" sounds a whole lot to my ears like "It won't need more than two digits for the year."

Comment: Or we can't use C# because Windows might not be around next year?

Comment: E.g. Apple's MacIntosh computers which have been based upon Motorola MC68000 series processors, PowerPC (IBM et all), and now Intel's x86 (IA-32(e)) processors. So yeah, portability is an issue for any system used long enough, and any programmer who hasn't been bitten by their code lasting longer than expected isn't experienced yet.

Comment: @Martin:  Twenty years from now, there will be a lot of C# programs people want to run, and so there will be a way to compile and run C# programs.  There's nothing inherently fixed about C#, although in twenty years I'd be surprised if it was still as popular as it is now.  However, in twenty years our CPUs will be significantly different.  An assembler program written in 1990 may well run nowadays, but it sure won't be optimal, and will run slower than compiled C.

Comment: That's what I meant - I have a lot more porting issues because a high-level framework changed from 6months ago than I do because the instructions in an x86 changed - especially since hand coded asm tends to stick to the simplest methods.

Comment: Even if M$ disappears, C# is mostly an open standard is it not, or am I thinking of something else?

Answer (score 2):

There was a vicious cycle as assembly became less commonplace: as higher level languages matured, assembly language instruction sets were built less for programmer convenience and more for the convenience of compilers.

So now, realistically, it may be very hard to make the right decisions on, say, which registers you should use or which instructions are slightly more efficient. Compilers can use heuristics to figure out which tradeoffs are likely to have the best payoff. We can probably think through smaller problems and find local optimizations that might beat our now pretty sophisticated compilers, but odds are that in the average case, a good compiler will do a better job on the first try than a good programmer probably will. Eventually, like John Henry, we might beat the machine, but we might seriously burn ourselves out getting there.

Our problems are also now quite different. In 1986 I was trying to figure out how to get a little more speed out of small programs that involved putting a few hundred pixels on the screen; I wanted the animation to be less jerky. A fair case for assembly language. Now I'm trying to figure out how to represent abstractions around contract language and servicer policy for mortgages, and I'd rather read something that looks close to the language that the business folks speak. Unlike LISP macros, Assembly macros don't enforce much in the way of rules, so even though you might be able to get something reasonably close to a DSL in a good assembler, it'll be prone to all sorts of quirks that won't cause me problems if I wrote the same code in Ruby, Boo, Lisp, C# or even F#.

If your problems are easy to express in efficient assembly language, though, more power to you.

Answer (score 2):

Ditto most of what others have said.

In the good old days before C was invented, when the only high level languages were things like COBOL and FORTRAN, there were lots of things that just weren't possible to do without resorting to assembler. It was the only way to get the full breadth of flexibility, to be able to access all the devices, etc. But then C was invented, and almost anything that was possible in assembly was possible in C. I have written very little assembly since then.

That said, I think it is a very useful exercise for new programmers to learn to write in assembler. Not because they would actually use it much, but because then you understand what is really happening inside the computer. I've seen lots of programming errors and inefficient code from programmers who clearly have no idea what's really happening with the bits and bytes and registers.

Comment: Yes, spot on. Fortran Disk and Tape I/O on IBM mainframes years ago was next to useless, so we wrote our own I/O routines in 370/Assembler and called them from the Fortan IV code.

And writing assembly code made me really understand the underlying architecture. I haven't written any assembly code now for quite a few years and all the younger people I work with have never written any - but I wish they would, it is so educational.

Answer (score 2):

I've been programming in assembly now for about a month.  I often write a piece of code in C and then compile it to assembly to assist me.  Perhaps I am not utilizing the full optimizing power of the C compiler but it appears that my C asm source is including unnecessary operations.  So I am beginning to see that the talk of a good C compiler outperforming a good assembly coder is not always true.

Anyways, my assembly programs are so fast.  And the more I use assembly the less time it takes me to write out my code because it's really not that hard.  Also the comment about assembly having poor legibility is not true.  If you label your programs correctly and make comments when there is additional elaboration needed you should be all set.  In fact in ways assembly is more clear to the programmer because they are seeing what is happening at the level of the processor.  I don't know about other programmers but for me I like knowing what's happening, rather than things being in a sort of black box.

With that said the real advantage of compilers is that a compiler can understand patterns and relationships and then automatically code them in the appropriate locations in the source.  One popular example are virtual functions in C++ which requires the compiler to optimally map function pointers.  However a compiler is limited to doing what the maker of the compiler allows the compiler to do.  This leads to programmers sometimes having to resort to doing bizarre things with their code , adding coding time, when they could have been done trivially with assembly.

Personally I think the marketplace heavily supports high level languages.  If assembly language was the only language in existence today then their would be about 70% less people programming and who knows where our world would be, probably back in the 90's.  Higher level languages appeal to a broader range of people.  This allows a higher supply of programmers to build the needed infrastructure of our world.  Developing nations like China and India benefit heavily from languages like Java.  These countries will fast develop their IT infrastructure and people will become more interconnected.    So my point is that high level languages are popular not because they produce superior code but because they help to meet demand in the world's marketplaces.

Comment: +1 for black box thing. Yep, we're using black boxes, and there are no way to peek into them (too easy). How does C# *foreach* really work? Who knows. Microsoft said, it's perfect. Then it must be.

Comment: Also, don't forget that with a 'high-level language' comes lots of other stuff that matters in the real world. C comes with the standard libraries (math, string processing, I/O etc.), and then the heavy weights like Java come with loads of other packages and libraries for connectivity, image processing, data processing, web dev etc. Its a question of using your time to focus on getting 1 detailed task highly performant on one platform (thus using assembly) versus spending the same time getting a **much** bigger task running on multiple platforms with minimal bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning assembly in comp org right now, and while it is interesting, it is also very inefficient to write in.  You have to keep alot more details in your head to get things working, and its also slower to write the same things.  For example, a simple 6 line for loop in C++ can equal 18 lines or more of assembly.

Personally, its alot of fun learning how things work down at the hardware level, and it gives me greater appreciation for how computing works.

Answer (score 1):

What C has over a good macro assembler is the language C.  Type checking.  Loop constructs.  Automatic stack management.  (Nearly) automatic variable management.  Dynamic memory techniques in assembler are a massive pain in the butt.  Doing a linked list properly is just down right scary compared to C or better yet list foo.insert().  And debugging - well, there's no contest on what is easier to debug.  HLLs win hands down there.

I've coded nearly half my career in assembler which makes it very easy for me to think in assmebler.  it helps me to see what the C compiler is doing which again helps me write code that the C compiler can efficiently handle.  A well thought out routine written in C can be written to output exactly what you want in assembler with a little work - and it's portable!  I've already had to rewrite a few older asm routines back to C for cross platform reasons and it's no fun.

No, I'll stick with C and deal with the occasional slight slowdown in performance against the productivity time I gain with HLL.

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer why I personally don't write programs in assembly more often, and the main reason is that it's **more tedious** to do. Also, I think that it is **easier to get things subtly wrong** without noticing immediately. E.g., you might change the way you use a register in one routine but forget to change this in one place. It'll assemble fine and you may not notice until much later.

That said, I do think there are still valid uses for assembly. For instance, I have a number of pretty optimised assembly routines for processing large amounts of data, using SIMD and following the paranoid "every bit is sacred"[quote V.Stob] approach. (But note that naive assembly implementations are often a lot worse than what a compiler would generate for you.)

Answer (score 1):

C is a macro assembler! And it's the best one!

It can do nearly everything assembly can, it can be portable and in most of the rare cases where it can't do something you can still use embedded assembly code. This leaves only a small fraction of programs that you absolutely need to write in assembly and nothing but assembly.

And the higher level abstractions and the portability make it more worthwhile for most people to write system software in C. And although you might not need portability now if you invest a lot of time and money in writing some program you might not want to limit yourself in what you'll be able to use it for in the future.

Answer (score 1):

People seem to forget that there is also the other direction.

Why are you writing in Assembler in the first place? Why not write the program in a truly low level language?

Instead of

```
mov eax, 0x123
add eax, 0x456
push eax
call printInt
```

you could just as well write

```
B823010000
0556040000
50 
FF15.....
```

That has so *many* advantages, you know the exact size of your program, you can reuse  the value of instructions as input for other instructions and you do not even need an assembler to write it, you can use any text editor...

And the reason you still prefer Assembler about this, is the reason other people prefer C...

Answer (score 0):

Because it's always that way: time pass and good things pass away too :(

But when you write asm code it's totally different feeling than when you code high-level langs, though you know it's much less productive. It's like you're a painter: you are free to draw anything you like the way you like with absolutely no restrictions(well, only by CPU features)... That is why I love it. It's a pity this language goes away. But while somebody still remembers it and codes it, it will never die!

Comment: True. On the other hand, there is the humiliation you experience when the cashier and the supermarket refuses to cash your check, disdainfully saying, "Oh, you program in a LOW-LEVEL language."

Answer (score 0):

$$$

A company hires a developer to help turn code into $$$.  The faster that **useful** code  can be produced, the faster the company can turn that code into $$$.

Higher level languages are generally better at churning out larger volumes of useful code.  This is not to say that assembly does not have its place, for there are times and places where nothing else will do.

Answer (score 0):

The advantage of HLL's is even greater when you compare assembly to a higher level language than C, e.g. Java or Python or Ruby.  For instance, these languages have garbage collection:  no need to worry about when to free a chunk of memory, and no memory leaks or bugs due to freeing too early.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned before, the reason for any tool to exist is how efficiently it can work. As HLLs can accomplish the same jobs as many lines of asm code I guess it's natural for assembly to be superseded by other languages. And for the close-to-hardware fiddling - there's inline assembly in C and other variants as per language. 
  Dr. Paul Carter in says in the [PC Assembly Language](http://www.drpaulcarter.com/pcasm/)

> "...a better understanding of how
>   computers really work at a lower level
>   than in programming languages like
>   Pascal. By gaining a deeper
>   understanding of how computers work,
>   the reader can often be much more
>   productive developing software in
>   higher level languages such as C and
>   C++. Learning to program in assembly
>   language is an excellent way to
>   achieve this goal."

We've got introduction to assembly in my college courses. It'll help to clear concepts. However I doubt any of us would write 90% of code in assembly. How relevant is in-depth assembly knowledge today?

Answer (score -2):

Flipping through these answers, I'd bet 9/10 of the responders have never worked with assembly.

This is an ages old question that comes up every so often and you get the same, mostly misinformed answers. If it weren't for portability, I'd still do everything in assembly myself. Even then, I code in C almost like I did in assembly.

Comment: +1 mentioning people without any asm experience, and another +1 should for "coding in C like asm". When I'm writing C++ (yes, CPP, not C) apps for embedded, I'm coding like it were asm, e.g. using no new/malloc() at all.

Comment: So you use lots of things like char buf[MAX_PATH] which then falls over when someone has data of MAX_PATH+n size? ;)

Comment: @paulm - You mean just like C does?

Comment: C won't have that issue unless like @ern0 said, they don't use malloc.

Comment: I sure hope assembler authors don't avoid the use of malloc(). Yes, on embedded you are memory-constrained. But do that on Unix or another desktop (or even most mobile OSes) and you're just unnecessarily restricting yourself and your users. Also: The less LOC you write, the less chance of mistake, which means higher level code is likely to have less errors than lower.

Comment: Just looked cause I was suspcious and, yep, I sure can tell the redditors and HNers are here.

Comment: In embedded environment there are several reason not to use malloc. 1. You have no popup window nor a simple stderr to say a "not enough memory, try again", you can max. flash a red led. 2. If there are ANY chance to run out of memory, then your design is bad. Imageine, you press brake pedal, and the car says: out of memory. Khm. 3. There's really no memory: 2 Kbytes, 4K, 32K. You have to scale your task to available memory in "design-time". 4. Maybe there is even no malloc(). The "operation system" does not support it. There is no operation system at all. 5. It's fun!

Answer (score -6):

The difference is - assembler is an art of code and a good painting in a proper artist's hands. You are smarter than crappy compiler code? If you are, use it or take care of your painting with c and assembler together.

Answer (score -8):

Oh hai, I'm a dataflow system. This App I'm running, are full of varrrious components. It's a distributed app, and it resides in 3 computers, on a powerful x86 and two smaller ARMs. Most of the components are written in C++, but there is a critical one written in ASM for the x86. Also, most components have several variations: compiled for different processors, also some components have special GPU versions. Shame or not, I have a script component (a wrapper component calls a script), which prints report, but only once a year. It doesn't even hurt that it's just a script, a slow script.

As a smart dataflow app, I know, my architecture fits only for certain tasks, where a signal/data is flowing thru a graph, e.g. automation, video/image processing, audio processing (all synthetisers use  dataflow) but fortunatelly these appliction areas are very horsepower hungry ones, where **optimization** is essential.

I am pretty sure that a nice day several other architectures will appear, which are also about optimisation (and about other things make programming easier etc.), and they will be able to cover more or other areas, which me, the dataflow can't.

So, the *"C vs ASM"* topic is not a real dilemma. It's like arguing of that wheter digital or analogue synths are better (as I mentioned, I'm engadged with synths). I advise, *make good music*. Or listen. Whatever. C is not versus ASM. Anyway, I never seen a C program attacked by an ASM one or vice versa.

Sorry for bad English, despite I'm not a new tehcnology, I'm not widely known, I'm a child. A promising one. Come, see my [profile](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=dataflow)!