# Is inline assembly language slower than native C++ code?

Tags: c++, c, performance, assembly

I tried to compare the performance of inline assembly language and C++ code, so I wrote a function that add two arrays of size 2000 for 100000 times. Here's the code:

```
#define TIMES 100000
void calcuC(int *x,int *y,int length)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < length; j++)
            x[j] += y[j];
    }
}


void calcuAsm(int *x,int *y,int lengthOfArray)
{
    __asm
    {
        mov edi,TIMES
        start:
        mov esi,0
        mov ecx,lengthOfArray
        label:
        mov edx,x
        push edx
        mov eax,DWORD PTR [edx + esi*4]
        mov edx,y
        mov ebx,DWORD PTR [edx + esi*4]
        add eax,ebx
        pop edx
        mov [edx + esi*4],eax
        inc esi
        loop label
        dec edi
        cmp edi,0
        jnz start
    };
}
```

Here's `main()`:

```
int main() {
    bool errorOccured = false;
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int *xC,*xAsm,*yC,*yAsm;
    xC = new int[2000];
    xAsm = new int[2000];
    yC = new int[2000];
    yAsm = new int[2000];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    {
        xC[i] = 0;
        xAsm[i] = 0;
        yC[i] = i;
        yAsm[i] = i;
    }
    time_t start = clock();
    calcuC(xC,yC,2000);

    //    calcuAsm(xAsm,yAsm,2000);
    //    for(int i = 0; i < 2000; i++)
    //    {
    //        if(xC[i] != xAsm[i])
    //        {
    //            cout<<"xC["<<i<<"]="<<xC[i]<<" "<<"xAsm["<<i<<"]="<<xAsm[i]<<endl;
    //            errorOccured = true;
    //            break;
    //        }
    //    }
    //    if(errorOccured)
    //        cout<<"Error occurs!"<<endl;
    //    else
    //        cout<<"Works fine!"<<endl;

    time_t end = clock();

    //    cout<<"time = "<<(float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC<<"\n";

    cout<<"time = "<<end - start<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Then I run the program five times to get the cycles of processor, which could be seen as time. Each time I call one of the function mentioned above only.

And here comes the result.

### Function of assembly version:

```
Debug   Release
---------------
732        668
733        680
659        672
667        675
684        694
Average:   677
```

### Function of C++ version:

```
Debug     Release
-----------------
1068      168
 999      166
1072      231
1002      166
1114      183
Average:  182
```

The C++ code in release mode is almost 3.7 times faster than the assembly code. Why?

I guess that the assembly code I wrote is not as effective as those generated by GCC. It's hard for a common programmer like me to wrote code faster than its opponent generated by a compiler.Does that mean I should not trust the performance of assembly language written by my hands, focus on C++ and forget about assembly language?

Comment: Pretty much. Handcoded assembly is appropriate in some circumstances, but care must be taken to ensure that the assembly version is indeed faster than what can be achieved with a higher level language.

Comment: You might find it instructive to study the code generated by the compiler, and try to understand why it's faster than your assembly version.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the compiler is better at writing asm than you. Modern compilers really are quite good.

Comment: Have you looked at the assembly GCC produced? Its possible GCC used MMX instructions. Your function is very parallel - you could potentially use N processors to compute the sum in 1/N th the time. Try a function where there is no hope for parallelization.

Comment: Hm, I would have expected a good compiler to do this ~100000 times faster...

Comment: No surprises there. If you're going to this, at least do it right.

Comment: It won't matter too much in this application but for your future notice, when you are measuring clock cycles for a program like this where you have no user input you really should have your process set itself to a realtime priority before you start to measure clock cycles to get a much more accurate measurement (although that won't change the conclusion of your results here ;).

Comment: @PlasmaHH: actually I was quite surprised, but Clang/LLVM does not optimize the loop over `TIMES` away. I expected it to be simplified into `x[j] += TIMES * y[j]` but it did not happen. Even when interchanging the loops manually to makes the loop over `TIMES` the inner one it still did not. *shoking*

Comment: @MatthieuM.: maybe some obscure language rules are preventing this? Or its time for a bug/enhancement report...

Comment: @PlasmaHH: Actually this becomes possible with the `restrict` qualifier, however Clang/LLVM fails to interchange the loops automatically and only optimizes this if the loops are interchanged...

Comment: One of the classic college assignments in processor design is to take the unoptimized compiler output and manually tweak the assembly till it runs significantly faster (e.g. at least 100x as fast). It's a fun and instructive exercise.

Comment: curious what compiler flags did you use in both cases?

Comment: Sure you should trust the performance of your assembly; it'll be exactly what you specify!  Actually you shouldn't trust the performance of the code generated by the compiler--the result will be much faster than what you think.

Comment: @DaxFohl: assembly performance is not easy to estimate when today's bottleneck is memory (in most cases) and not instruction count. Memory access patterns are most often the critical piece (playing nice with prefetching, avoiding branches) and whether you use C or assembly is not so important.

Comment: Epic answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2685541/372860

Comment: You should post the assembly code that your compiler generates.

Comment: The only way you can compare, is taking the assembly from the compiler, improving on that as much as you can, and then benchmark.  If you can't, the compiler is better than you and you live in the happy world of "no point checking the ASM ever".  If you can, welcome to hell where you can't trust any of your tools.

Answer (score 288, accepted):

Yes, most times.

First of all you start from wrong assumption that a low-level language (assembly in this case) will always produce faster code than high-level language (C++ and C in this case). It's not true. Is C code always faster than Java code? No because there is another variable: programmer. The way you write code and knowledge of architecture details greatly influence performance (as you saw in this case).

You can **always** produce an example where handmade assembly code is better than compiled code but **usually** it's a fictional example or a single routine not a *true* program of 500.000+ lines of C++ code). I think compilers will produce better assembly code 95% times and **sometimes, only some rare times,** you may need to write assembly code for few, short, [highly used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29), [performance critical](http://www.douglocke.com/Downloads/Performance-Critical%20Systems%20White%20Paper.pdf) routines or when you have to access features your favorite high-level language does not expose. Do you want a touch of this complexity? Read [this awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40355466/1207195) here on SO.

Why this?

First of all because compilers can do optimizations that we can't even imagine (see [this short list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler)) and they will do them in *seconds* (when [we may need days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685541/1207195)).

When you code in assembly you have to make well-defined functions with a well-defined call interface. However they can take in account [whole-program optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) and [inter-procedural optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2685541/1207195) such 
as [register allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation), [constant propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding#Constant_propagation), [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination), [instruction scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_scheduling) and other complex, not obvious optimizations ([Polytope model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytope_model), for example). On [RISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_instruction_set_computing) architecture guys stopped worrying about this many years ago (instruction scheduling, for example, is very hard to [tune by hand](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~dima/cs580a/spec_wake_micro00.pdf)) and modern [CISC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computer) CPUs have very long [pipelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) too.

For some complex microcontrollers even *system* libraries are written in C instead of assembly because their compilers produce a better (and easy to maintain) final code.

Compilers sometimes can [automatically use some MMX/SIMDx instructions](http://ds9a.nl/gcc-simd/example.html) by themselves, and if you don't use them you simply can't compare (other answers already reviewed your assembly code very well).
Just for loops this is a [short list of loop optimizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_transformation) of what is **commonly** checked for by a compiler (do you think you could do it by yourself when your schedule has been decided for a C# program?) If you write something in assembly, I think you have to consider at least some [simple optimizations](http://www.mark.masmcode.com). The school-book example for arrays is to [unroll the cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) (its size is known at compile time). Do it and run your test again.

These days it's also really uncommon to need to use assembly language for another reason: the [plethora of different CPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Chronology). Do you want to support them all? Each has a specific [microarchitecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microarchitecture) and some [specific instruction sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_instruction_listings). They have different number of functional units and assembly instructions should be arranged to keep them all *busy*. If you write in C you may use [PGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profile-guided_optimization) but in assembly you will then need a great knowledge of that specific architecture (and **rethink and redo everything for another architecture**). For small tasks the compiler *usually* does it better, and for complex tasks *usually* the work isn't repaid (and [compiler *may* do better](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=74953) anyway).

If you sit down and you take a look at your code probably you'll see that you'll gain more to redesign your algorithm than to translate to assembly (read this [great post here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort/927773#927773)), there are high-level optimizations (and hints to compiler) you can effectively apply before you need to resort to assembly language. It's probably worth to mention that often using intrinsics you will have performance gain your're looking for and compiler will still be able to perform most of its optimizations.

All this said, even when you can produce a 5~10 times faster assembly code, you should ask your customers if they prefer to **pay** one week of **your time** or to **buy a 50$ faster CPU**. Extreme optimization more often than not (and especially in LOB applications) is simply not required from most of us.

Comment: @drhirsch It's heartbreaking to hear from you:),but I know what's my work and what's not.Thank you all!

Comment: So the compiler is better at writing code than people are. Good to know.

Comment: Of course not. I think it's better of 95% of people in 99% of times. Sometimes because it's simply to costly (because of **complex** math) or time spending (then costly again). Sometimes because we simply did forget about optimizations...

Comment: @ja72 - no, it's not better at *writing* code. It's better at *optimizing* code.

Comment: It's counter-intuitive until you really consider it.  In the same way, VM based machines are starting to make runtime optimizations that compilers simply don't have the information to make.

Comment: @Bill Not really true. Compilers have just as much information as VMs do. Tis just that compilers are still usually (minutely) faster than VMs without considering such things. (Any statistical information a VM has about the code can be provided to a compiler if it supports profile guided optimization, as most compilers do nowadays) Whereas it's trivial to make either a compiler or VM that considers more optimizations than would be practical to do by hand.

Comment: @Billy VMs know the CPU architecture and which instructions it supports, the compiler can't use these instructions because it must be cautious and not use them to support CPUs that don't support them.

Comment: @M28: Compilers can use the same instructions. Sure, they pay for it in terms of binary size (because they have to provide a fallback path in the event those instructions aren't supported). Also, for the most part, the "new instructions" that would be added are SMID instructions anyway, which both VMs and Compilers are pretty horrible at utilizing. VMs pay for this feature in that they have to compile the code at startup.

Comment: @Billy a VM can notice that a given use case more often than not selects values that cause a routine not to do any work within a given method call--it can then optimize that call out completely.  If a compiler could do that, it could only be through a runtime (and then it has a runtime and falls on the other side of the discussion).  A runtime-compiled language can also adopt new optimizations without a manual recompile step--say for a new CPU instruction (or a new cpu)...  I'm just saying that in many cases "better" is not as obvious as one would think.

Comment: @BillK: PGO does the same thing for compilers.

Comment: @BillK You are a java guy, aren't you? Sometimes it shows ;-) Ok, now I need to shut up ;-)

Comment: I don't particularly try to hide it, but that's a pretty strange way to categorize the world into "Java people" and "Not Java People".  You could also call me a "Not holding lit stick of dynamite" guy--which is even more accurate because although I spent years developing professionally in C and C++ (and various other languages) I Never held any anything bigger than a lit firecracker in my hands.

Comment: @BillK: I think drhirsch was just making fun of your insistance that VMs are *the* performance killers, when they are just using traditional compilation/optimization technics. Regarding "avoiding the manual recompile", it's of little interest to most people really interested in performance. Whether you start from some binary intermediate language or from the source code to produce the new optimized binary (whether native or not) is the same principle as far as compiler go, and people really interested in performance will use it, even if it incurs a manual operation.

Comment: I understand and I wasn't upset or anything--I just find it kind of amusing, when I was young the argument was that C could never be as fast as assembly, now VMs can never be as fast as compiled, I wonder what it will look like in 10 years.  Stuff isn't always intuitive.

Comment: @BillK: Of course a VM can be as fast as compiled; after all, most VMs *are* JIT compilers. It's just that most VMs aren't often willing to pay the optimization time cost to get there. Some of the modern VMs are really really good at placing optimization bets though. My point above is just that there are always tradeoffs, and that generally speaking compilers and VMs will (generally speaking_ be comparable with similar written code. The bigger overhead with most "VM" languages is garbage collection rather than JIT compilation. (Though GC has perf advantages too; e.g. allocation is really fast)

Comment: `You can always produce an example where handmade assembly code is better than compiled code` - in theory, that's not quite true. there's no reason a compiler could not emit the absolutely quickest possible assembly code (it's just very unlikely), and likewise, when writing in assembly it's also theoretically possible to write the absolutely quickest possible assembly code (it's just very unlikely, i think [these guys tried though](https://github.com/luke-jr/cgminer/blob/b16beb0df89e3b9c2c75daf994f0520435e6cd8e/x86_32/sha256_xmm.asm))

Comment: @hans I agree, it's possible, indeed, and extremely unlikely (given a finite compilation time and finite resources for writing the optimizer). Interesting code BTW, it would be nice to see a comparison with good C code but in this case I admit that assembly might even be more portable across compilers than intrinsics in C.

Comment: Getting clang and gcc to produce optimal machine code for platforms like the Cortex-M0 is hard, even when performing tasks which should be simple (e.g. `for (int i=0; i<n; i+=2) foo[i] += 0x12345678;` hand optimizing the assembly to five instructions per loop, or 14 per 4x-unrolled loop, is pretty simple.  Coaxing clang to generate a five-instruction loop is hard, and I can't figure out any way to write the code so gcc will do so, though curiously enough I could manage a six-instruction loop in -O0 which was better than the eight-instruction loop gcc produced from the same code...

Comment: ...wish optimizations enabled.

Comment: Finally, a correct use of "plethora"!

Answer (score 197):

Your assembly code is suboptimal and may be improved:

- You are pushing and popping a register ([EDX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#32-bit)) in your inner loop. This should be moved out of the loop.
- You reload the array pointers in every iteration of the loop. This should moved out of the loop.
- You use the `loop` instruction, which is [known to be dead slow on most modern CPUs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently) (possibly a result of using an ancient assembly book*)
- You take no advantage of manual loop unrolling.
- You don't use available [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions.

So unless you vastly improve your skill-set regarding assembler, it doesn't make sense for you to write assembler code for performance.

*Of course I don't know if you really got the `loop` instruction from an ancient assembly book. But you almost never see it in real world code, as every compiler out there is smart enough to not emit `loop`, you only see it in IMHO bad and outdated books.

Comment: compilers may still emit `loop` (and many "deprecated" instructions) if you optimize for size

Comment: @phuclv well yes, but original question was exactly about speed, not size.

Answer (score 61):

Even before delving into assembly, there are code transformations that exist at a higher level.

```
static int const TIMES = 100000;

void calcuC(int *x, int *y, int length) {
  for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
      x[j] += y[j];
    }
  }
}
```

can be transformed into via [Loop Rotation](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#loop-rotate):

```
static int const TIMES = 100000;

void calcuC(int *x, int *y, int length) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
      for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
        x[j] += y[j];
      }
    }
}
```

which is much better as far as memory locality goes.

This could be optimizes further, doing `a += b` X times is equivalent to doing `a += X * b` so we get:

```
static int const TIMES = 100000;

void calcuC(int *x, int *y, int length) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length; ++j) {
      x[j] += TIMES * y[j];
    }
}
```

however it seems my favorite optimizer (LLVM) does not perform this transformation.

**[edit]** I found that the transformation is performed if we had the `restrict` qualifier to `x` and `y`. Indeed without this restriction, `x[j]` and `y[j]` could alias to the same location which makes this transformation erroneous. **[end edit]**

Anyway, *this* is, I think, the optimized C version. Already it is much simpler. Based on this, here is my crack at ASM (I let Clang generate it, I am useless at it):

```
calcuAsm:                               # @calcuAsm
.Ltmp0:
    .cfi_startproc
# BB#0:
    testl   %edx, %edx
    jle .LBB0_2
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_1:                                # %.lr.ph
                                        # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
    imull   $100000, (%rsi), %eax   # imm = 0x186A0
    addl    %eax, (%rdi)
    addq    $4, %rsi
    addq    $4, %rdi
    decl    %edx
    jne .LBB0_1
.LBB0_2:                                # %._crit_edge
    ret
.Ltmp1:
    .size   calcuAsm, .Ltmp1-calcuAsm
.Ltmp2:
    .cfi_endproc
```

I am afraid I don't understand where all those instructions come from, however you can always have fun and try and see how it compares... but I'd still use the optimized C version rather than the assembly one, in code, much more portable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Well,it's a little confusing that when I took the class named "Compiler principles",I learned that the compiler will optimize our code by many means. Does that mean we need to optimize our code manually?Can we do a better job than the compiler? That's the question that always confuse me.

Comment: @user957121: we can optimize it better when we have more information. Specifically here what hinders the compiler is the possible *aliasing* between `x` and `y`. That is, the compiler cannot be sure that for all `i,j` in `[0, length)` we have `x + i != y + j`. If there is overlap, then optimization is impossible. The C language introduced the `restrict` keyword to tell the compiler that two pointers cannot alias, however it does not work for arrays because they can still overlap even if they don't exactly alias.

Comment: Current GCC and Clang auto-vectorize (after checking for non-overlap if you omit `__restrict`).  SSE2 is baseline for x86-64, and with shuffling SSE2 can do 2x 32-bit multiplies at once (producing 64-bit products, hence the shuffling to put the results back together). https://godbolt.org/z/r7F_uo.  (SSE4.1 is needed for `pmulld`: packed 32x32 => 32-bit multiply).  GCC has a neat trick of turning constant integer multipliers into shift/add (and/or subtract), which is good for multipliers with few bits set.  Clang's shuffle-heavy code is going to bottleneck on shuffle throughput on Intel CPUs.

Answer (score 41):

**Short answer:** yes.

**Long answer:** yes, unless you really know what you're doing, and have a reason to do so.

Comment: and then only if you've run an assembly level profiling tool like vtune for intel chips to see where you may be able to improve on things

Comment: This technically answers the question but is also completely useless. A -1 from me.

Comment: Very long answer: "Yes, unless you feel like changing your whole code whenever a new(er) CPU is used. Pick the best algorithm, but let the compiler do the optimization"

Answer (score 35):

I have fixed my asm code:

```
  __asm
{   
    mov ebx,TIMES
 start:
    mov ecx,lengthOfArray
    mov esi,x
    shr ecx,1
    mov edi,y
label:
    movq mm0,QWORD PTR[esi]
    paddd mm0,QWORD PTR[edi]
    add edi,8
    movq QWORD PTR[esi],mm0
    add esi,8
    dec ecx 
    jnz label
    dec ebx
    jnz start
};
```

Results for Release version:

```
 Function of assembly version: 81
 Function of C++ version: 161
```

The assembly code in release mode is almost 2 times faster than the C++.

Comment: Now if you start using SSE instead of MMX (register name is `xmm0` instead of `mm0`), you will get another speedup by a factor of two ;-)

Comment: I changed, got 41 for assembly version. It is in 4 times faster :)

Comment: also can get up to 5% more if use all xmm registers

Comment: Now if you think about the time it actually took you: assembly, about 10 hours or so? C++, a few minutes I guess? There's a clear winner here, unless it is performance-critical code.

Comment: A good compiler will already auto-vectorize with `paddd xmm` (after checking for overlap between `x` and `y`, because you didn't use `int *__restrict x`).  For example gcc does that: https://godbolt.org/z/c2JG0-.  Or after inlining into `main`, it shouldn't need to check for overlap because it can see the allocation and prove they're non-overlapping.  (And it would get to assume 16-byte alignment on some x86-64 implementations, too, which isn't the case for the stand-alone definition.)  And if you compile with `gcc -O3 -march=native`, you can get 256-bit or 512-bit vectorization.

Answer (score 24):

> Does that mean I should not trust the performance of assembly language written by my hands

Yes, that is exactly what it means, and it is true for *every* language. If you don't know how to write efficient code in language X, then you should not trust your ability to write efficient code in X. And so, if you want efficient code, you should use another language.

Assembly is particularly sensitive to this, because, well, what you see is what you get. You write the specific instructions that you want the CPU to execute. With high level languages, there is a compiler in betweeen, which can transform your code and remove many inefficiencies. With assembly, you're on your own.

Comment: I think it is in order to write that especially for a modern x86 processor it is exceptionally difficult to write efficient assembly code due to the presence of pipelines, multiple execution units and other gimmicks inside every core. Writing code that balances the usage of all these resources in order to get the highest execution speed will often result in code with unstraightforward logic that "shouldn't" be fast according to "conventional" assembly wisdom. But for less complex CPUs it is my experience that the C compiler's code generation can be bettered significantly.

Comment: The C compilers code *can* be usually be bettered, even on a modern x86 CPU. But you have to understand the CPU well, which is harder to do with a modern x86 CPU. That's my point. If you don't understand the hardware you're targeting, then you won't be able to optimize for it. And then the compiler will likely do a better job

Comment: And if you really want to blow the compiler away you have to be creative and optimize in ways the compiler cannot. It's a tradeoff for time/reward that's why C is a scripting language for some and intermediate code for a higher level language for others. For me though, assembly is more for the fun :). much like http://www.grc.com/smgassembly.htm

Answer (score 23):

The only reason to use assembly language nowadays is to use some features not accessible by the language.

This applies to:

- Kernel programming that needs to access to certain hardware features such as the MMU
- High performance programming that uses very specific vector or multimedia instructions not supported by your compiler.

But current compilers are quite smart, they can even replace two separate statements like
`d = a / b; r = a % b;` with a single instruction that calculates the division and remainder in one go if it is available, even if C does not have such operator.

Comment: There's other places for ASM besides those two.  Namely, a bignum library will usually be significantly faster in ASM than C, due to having access to carry flags and the upper part of multiplication and such.  You can do these things in portable C as well, but they're very slow.

Comment: @MooingDuck That might be considered as accessing hardware hardware features that are not directly available in the language... But as long as you are just *translating* your high level code to assembly by hand, the compiler will beat you.

Comment: it is that, but it is not kernel programming, nor vendor specific.  Though with slight workding changes, it could easily fall into either category.  Id guess ASM when you want the performance of processor instructions that have no C mapping.

Comment: @fortran Your basically just saying if you don't optimize your code it won't be as fast as the code the compiler optimized. The optimization is the reason one would write assembly in the first place. If you mean translate then optimize there is no reason the compiler will beat you unless you aren't good at optimizing assembly. So to beat the compiler you have to optimize in ways the compiler cannot. It's pretty self explanatory. *The only reason to write assembly is if you are better than a compiler/interpreter*. That's always been the practical reason to write assembly.

Comment: @Hawken What I'm saying is that in 99.9999% (one in a million and I might be short) of the cases *you aren't good at optimizing assembly*. Plain simple, get over it.

Comment: Just saying: Clang has access to the carry flags, 128 bit multiplication and so on through built-in functions. And it can integrate all these into its normal optimisation algorithms.

Answer (score 21):

It is true that a modern compiler does an amazing job at code optimization, yet I would still encourage you to keep on learning assembly.

First of all you are clearly **not intimidated by it**, that's a great, great plus, next - you're on the right track by **profiling in order to validate or discard your speed assumptions**, you are asking for **input from experienced people**, and you have the greatest optimizing tool known to mankind:  **a brain**.

As your experience increases, you'll learn when and where to use it (usually the tightest, innermost loops in your code, after you have deeply optimized at an algorithmic level).

For inspiration I would recommend you lookup **Michael Abrash**'s articles (if you haven't heard from him, he is an optimization guru; he even collaborated with John Carmack in the optimization of the Quake software renderer!)

> "there ain't no such thing as the fastest code" - Michael Abrash

Comment: I believe one of Michael Abrash books is the graphics programming black book. But he's not the only one to use assembly, Chris Sawyer wrote the first two roller coaster tycoon games in assembly by himself.

Answer (score 14):

I have changed asm code:

```
 __asm
{ 
    mov ebx,TIMES
 start:
    mov ecx,lengthOfArray
    mov esi,x
    shr ecx,2
    mov edi,y
label:
    mov eax,DWORD PTR [esi]
    add eax,DWORD PTR [edi]
    add edi,4   
    dec ecx 
    mov DWORD PTR [esi],eax
    add esi,4
    test ecx,ecx
    jnz label
    dec ebx
    test ebx,ebx
    jnz start
};
```

Results for Release version:

```
 Function of assembly version: 41
 Function of C++ version: 161
```

The assembly code in release mode is almost 4 times faster than the C++. 
IMHo, the speed of assembly code depends from Programmer

Comment: Yeah,my code really needs to be optimized.Good work for you and thanks!

Comment: It is four times faster because you only do a quarter of the work :-) The `shr ecx,2` is superfluous, because the array length is already given in `int` and not in byte. So you basically achieve the same speed. You could try the  `paddd` from harolds answer, this will really be faster.

Answer (score 13):

it is very interesting topic!
I have changed the MMX by SSE in Sasha's code
Here is my results:

```
Function of C++ version:      315
Function of assembly(simply): 312
Function of assembly  (MMX):  136
Function of assembly  (SSE):  62
```

The assembly code with SSE is 5 times faster than the C++

Answer (score 12):

Most high-level languages compilers are very optimized and know what they are doing. You can try and dump the disassemble code and compare it with your native assembly. I believe you will see some nice tricks that your compiler is using.

Just for example, even that I am not sure it is right any more :) :

Doing:

```
mov eax,0
```

cost more cycles than

```
xor eax,eax
```

which does the same thing.

The compiler knows all these tricks and uses them.

Comment: Still true, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396527/any-reason-to-do-a-xor-eax-eax/1396552#1396552. Not because of the used cycles, but because of the reduced memory footprint.

Answer (score 10):

The compiler beat you. I'll give it a try, but I won't make any guarantees. I will assume that the "multiplication" by TIMES is meant to make it a more relevant performance test, that `y` and `x` are 16-aligned, and that `length` is a non-zero multiple of 4. That's probably all true anyway.

```
  mov ecx,length
  lea esi,[y+4*ecx]
  lea edi,[x+4*ecx]
  neg ecx
loop:
  movdqa xmm0,[esi+4*ecx]
  paddd xmm0,[edi+4*ecx]
  movdqa [edi+4*ecx],xmm0
  add ecx,4
  jnz loop
```

Like I said, I make no guarantees. But I'll be surprised if it can be done much faster - the bottleneck here is memory throughput even if everything is a L1 hit.

Comment: I think the complex addressing is slowing your code down, if you change the code to `mov ecx, length, lea ecx,[ecx*4], mov eax,16... add ecx,eax` and then just use [esi+ecx] everywhere you'll avoid 1 cycle stall per instruction speeding up the loop lots. (If you have the latest Skylake then this does not apply). The add reg,reg just makes the loop tighter, which may or may not help.

Comment: @Johan that shouldn't be a stall, just an extra cycle latency, but sure it can't hurt to not have it.. I wrote this code for Core2 which didn't have that issue. Isn't r+r also "complex"  btw?

Answer (score 7):

*Just blindly implementing the exact same algorithm, instruction by instruction, in assembly is **guaranteed** to be slower than what the compiler can do.*

It's because even the smallest optimization the compiler does is better than your rigid code with no optimization at all.

Of course, it is possible to beat the compiler, especially if it's a small, localized part of the code, I even had to do it myself to get an approx. 4x speed up, but in this case we have to heavily rely on good knowledge of the hardware and numerous, seemingly counter-intuitive tricks.

Comment: I think this depends on the language and compiler. I can imagine an extremely inefficient C compiler whose output could easily be beaten by a human writing straightforward assembly. The GCC, not so much.

Comment: With C/++ compilers being such an undertaking, and only 3 major ones around, they tend to be rather good at what they do. It's still (very) possible in certain circumstances that hand-written assembly will be faster; a lot of math libraries drop to asm to better handle multiple/wide values. So while guaranteed is a bit too strong, it is likely.

Comment: @peachykeen: I did not mean that assembly is guaranteed to be slower than C++ in general. I meant that "guarantee" in the case where you have a C++ code and blindly translate it line by line to assembly. Read the last paragraph of my answer too :)

Answer (score 5):

As a compiler i would replace a loop with a fixed size to a lot of execution tasks.

```
int a = 10;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    a = a + i;
}
```

will produce

```
int a = 10;
a = a + 0;
a = a + 1;
a = a + 2;
```

and eventually it will know that "a = a + 0;" is useless so it will remove this line.
Hopefully something in your head now willing to attach some optimization options as a comment. All those very effective optimizations will make the compiled language faster.

Comment: And unless `a` is volatile, there is a good chance that the compiler will just do `int a = 13;` from the very beginning.

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly what it means. Leave the micro-optimizations to the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

I love this example because it demonstrates an important lesson about low-level code. Yes, you *can* write assembly that is as fast as your C code. This is tautologically true, but doesn't necessarily *mean* anything. Clearly *somebody* can, otherwise the assembler wouldn't know the appropriate optimizations.

Likewise, the same principle applies as you go up the hierarchy of language abstraction. Yes, you *can* write a parser in C that is as fast as a quick-and-dirty perl script, and many people do. But that doesn't mean that because you used C, your code will be fast. In many cases, the higher-level languages do optimizations that you may have never even considered.

Answer (score 3):

In many cases, the optimal way to perform some task may depend upon the context in which the task is performed.  If a routine is written in assembly language, it will generally not be possible for the sequence of instructions to be varied based upon context.  As a simple example, consider the following simple method:

```
inline void set_port_high(void)
{
  (*((volatile unsigned char*)0x40001204) = 0xFF);
}
```

A compiler for 32-bit ARM code, given the above, would likely render it as something like:

```
ldr  r0,=0x40001204
mov  r1,#0
strb r1,[r0]
[a fourth word somewhere holding the constant 0x40001204]
```

or perhaps

```
ldr  r0,=0x40001000  ; Some assemblers like to round pointer loads to multiples of 4096
mov  r1,#0
strb r1,[r0+0x204]
[a fourth word somewhere holding the constant 0x40001000]
```

That could be optimized slightly in hand-assembled code, as either:

```
ldr  r0,=0x400011FF
strb r0,[r0+5]
[a third word somewhere holding the constant 0x400011FF]
```

or

```
mvn  r0,#0xC0       ; Load with 0x3FFFFFFF
add  r0,r0,#0x1200  ; Add 0x1200, yielding 0x400011FF
strb r0,[r0+5]
```

Both of the hand-assembled approaches would require 12 bytes of code space rather than 16; the latter would replace a "load" with an "add", which would on an ARM7-TDMI execute two cycles faster.  If the code was going to be executed in a context where r0 was don't-know/don't-care, the assembly language versions would thus be somewhat better than the compiled version.  On the other hand, suppose the compiler knew that some register [e.g. r5] was going to hold a value that was within 2047 bytes of the desired address 0x40001204 [e.g. 0x40001000], and further knew that some other register [e.g. r7] was going to hold a value whose low bits were 0xFF.  In that case, a compiler could optimize the C version of the code to simply:

```
strb r7,[r5+0x204]
```

Much shorter and faster than even the hand-optimized assembly code.  Further, suppose set_port_high occurred in the context:

```
int temp = function1();
set_port_high();
function2(temp); // Assume temp is not used after this
```

Not at all implausible when coding for an embedded system.  If `set_port_high` is written in assembly code, the compiler would have to move r0 (which holds the return value from `function1`) somewhere else before invoking the assembly code, and then move that value back to r0 afterward (since `function2` will expect its first parameter in r0), so the "optimized" assembly code would need five instructions.  Even if the compiler didn't know of any registers holding the address or the value to store, its four-instruction version (which it could adapt to use any available registers--not necessarily r0 and r1) would beat the "optimized" assembly-language version.  If the compiler had the necessary address and data in r5 and r7 as described earlier, `function1` would not alter those registers, and thus it could replace `set_port_high` with a single `strb` instruction--*four instructions smaller and faster* than the "hand-optimized" assembly code.

Note that hand-optimized assembly code can often outperform a compiler in cases where the programmer knows the precise program flow, but compilers shine in cases where a piece of code is written before its context is known, or where one piece of source code may be invoked from multiple contexts [if `set_port_high` is used in fifty different places in the code, the compiler could independently decide for each of those how best to expand it].

In general, I would suggest that assembly language is apt to yield the greatest performance improvements in those cases where each piece of code can be approached from a very limited number of contexts, and is apt to be detrimental to performance in places where a piece of code may be approached from many different contexts.  Interestingly (and conveniently) the cases where assembly is most beneficial to performance are often those where the code is most straightforward and easy to read.  The places that assembly language code would turn into a gooey mess are often those where writing in assembly would offer the smallest performance benefit.

[Minor note: there are some places where assembly code can be used to yield a hyper-optimized gooey mess; for example, one piece of code I did for the ARM needed to fetch a word from RAM and execute one of about twelve routines based upon the upper six bits of the value (many values mapped to the same routine).  I think I optimized that code to something like:

```
ldrh  r0,[r1],#2! ; Fetch with post-increment
ldrb  r1,[r8,r0 asr #10]
sub   pc,r8,r1,asl #2
```

The register r8 always held the address of the main dispatch table (within the loop where the code spend 98% of its time, nothing ever used it for any other purpose); all 64 entries referred to addresses in the 256 bytes preceding it.  Since the primary loop had in most cases a hard execution-time limit of about 60 cycles, the nine-cycle fetch and dispatch was very instrumental toward meeting that goal.  Using a table of 256 32-bit addresses would have been one cycle faster, but would have gobbled up 1KB of very precious RAM [flash would have added more than one wait state].  Using 64 32-bit addresses would have required adding an instruction to mask off some bits from the fetched word, and would still have gobbled up 192 more bytes than the table I actually used.  Using the table of 8-bit offsets yielded very compact and fast code, but not something I would expect a compiler would ever come up with; I also would not expect a compiler to dedicate a register "full time" to holding the table address.

The above code was designed to run as a self-contained system; it could periodically call C code, but only at certain times when the hardware with which it was communicating could safely be put into an "idle" state for two roughly-one-millisecond intervals every 16ms.

Answer (score 2):

In recent times, all the speed optimisations that I have done were replacing brain damaged slow code with just reasonable code. But for things were speed was really critical and I put serious effort into making something fast, the result was always an iterative process, where each iteration gave more insight into the problem, finding ways how to solve the problem with fewer operations. The final speed always depended on how much insight I got into the problem. If at any stage I used assembly code, or C code that was over-optimised, the process of finding a better solution would have suffered and the end result would be slower.

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here seem to exclude one aspect: sometimes we don't write code to achieve a specific aim, but for the sheer *fun* of it. It may not be economical to invest the time to do so, but arguably there is no greater satisfaction than beating the fastest compiler optimized code snippet in speed with a manually rolled asm alternative.

Comment: When you just want to beat the compiler, it's usually easier to take its asm output for your function and turn that into a stand-alone asm function that you tweak.  Using *inline* asm is a bunch of extra work to get the interface between C++ and asm correct and check that it's compiling to optimal code.  (But at least when just doing it for fun, you don't have to worry about it defeating optimizations like constant-propagation when the function inlines into something else.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).

Comment: See also [the Collatz-conjecture C++ vs. hand-written asm Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/why-is-this-c-code-faster-than-my-hand-written-assembly-for-testing-the-collat/40355466#40355466) for more on beating the compiler for fun :)  And also suggestions on how to use what you learn to modify the C++ to help the compiler make better code.

Comment: @PeterCordes So what you're saying is you agree.

Comment: Yes, asm is fun, except that *inline* asm is usually the wrong choice even for playing around.  This is technically an inline-asm question, so it would be good to at least address this point in your answer.  Also, this is really more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: OK agreed. I used to be an asm only guy but that was the 80ies.

Comment: These days compilers can sometimes make near-optimal asm if you hand-hold them to it by modifying your C source.  And sometimes they spot an optimization you didn't while you're doing that.  But this can get un-fun quickly in cases where they don't "see" the asm trick you want them to use.

Answer (score 1):

> C++ is faster unless you are using assembly language with deeper
>   knowledge with the correct way.

When I code in ASM, I reorganize the instructions manually so the CPU can execute more of them in parallel when logically possible. I barely use RAM when I code in ASM for example: There could be 20000+ lines of code in ASM and I not ever once used push/pop.

You could potentially jump in the middle of the opcode to self-modify the code and the behavior without the possible penalty of self-modifying code. Accessing registers takes 1 tick(sometimes takes .25 ticks) of the CPU.Accessing the RAM could take hundreds.

For my last ASM adventure, I never once used the RAM to store a variable(for thousands of lines of ASM). ASM could be potentially unimaginably faster than C++. But it depends on a lot of variable factors such as:

```
1. I was writing my apps to run on the bare metal.
2. I was writing my own boot loader that was starting my programs in ASM so there was no OS management in the middle.
```

I am now learning C# and C++ because i realized productivity matters!!
You could try to do the fastest imaginable programs using pure ASM alone in the free time. But in order to produce something, use some high level language.

For example, the last program I coded was using JS and GLSL and I never noticed any performance issue, even speaking about JS which is slow. This is because the mere concept of programming the GPU for 3D makes the speed of the language that sends the commands to the GPU almost irrelevant.

The speed of assembler alone on the bare metal is irrefutable.
Could it be even slower inside C++? - It could be because you are writing assembly code with a compiler not using an assembler to start with.

My personal council is to never write assembly code if you can avoid it, even though I love assembly.

Answer (score -3):

Assembly could be faster if your compiler generates a lot of [OO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Criticism) support code.

**Edit:**

To downvoters: the OP wrote "should I ... focus on C++ and forget about assembly language?" and I stand by my answer. You always need to keep an eye on the code OO generates, particularly when using methods. Not forgetting about assembly language means that you will periodically review the assembly your OO code generates which I believe is a must for writing well-performing software.

Actually, this pertains to all compileable code, not just OO.

Comment: -1: I don't see any OO feature being used. Your argument is the same as "assembly could also be faster if your compiler adds a million NOPs."

Comment: I was unclear, this is a actually a C question. If you write C code for a C++ compiler you aren't writing C++ code and you won't get any OO stuff. Once you start writing in real C++, using OO stuff you have to be very knowledgeable to get the compiler to not generate OO support code.

Comment: so your answer isnt about the question?  (Also, clarifications go in the answer, not comments.  Comments can be deleted anytime with no notice, notification, or history.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you mean by OO "support code". Of course, if you use a lot of RTTI and suchlike, the compiler will have to create lots of extra instructions to support those features – but any problem that's sufficiently high-level to ratify use of RTTI is too complex to be feasibly writable in assembly. What you can do, of course, is write only the abstract outside interface as OO, dispatching to performance-optimized pure procedural code where it's critical. But, depending on the application, C, Fortran, CUDA or simply C++ without virtual inheritance might be better than assembly here.

Comment: @leftaroundabout the feasability of writing something in assembly will also be highly dependent on the programmer.

Comment: No. At least not very likely. There is a thing in C++ called the zero overhead rule, and this applies most of the time. Learn more about OO - you will find out that in the end it improves readability of your code, improves code quality, increases coding speed, increases robustness. Also for embedded - but use C++ as it gives you more control, embedded+OO the Java way will cost you.

Comment: Wrong. No relation to OO. Compilers can optimize better than human programmers.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: compilers and their optimization strategies were written by programmers so there are some programmers that can optimize better than compilers. Since OO, generally speaking, is less WYSIWYG than, say, C it is not a bad idea to learn what OO constructs affect performance negatively and utilize other constructs instead.