# How to find the largest element of an array of known size?

Tags: c

I need to find the largest element in an array that contains exactly 16 integers. I'm considering two possible implementations. First, the sensible implementation:

```
int largest = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
  const int val = array[i];
  if (val > largest) {
    largest = val;
  }
}
```

And then there's the slightly insane implementation that takes advantage of the fact that the size of the array is known:

```
const int max_value =
  max(
    max(
      max(
        max(array[0], array[1]),
        max(array[2], array[3])),
      max(
        max(array[4], array[5]),
        max(array[6], array[7]))),
    max(
      max(
        max(array[8], array[9])
        max(array[10], array[11])),
      max(
        max(array[12], array[13])
        max(array[14], array[15]))));
```

Which is the better implementation? Is `max` typically implemented in hardware?

Comment: The amount of times you call max in the insane implementation probably wouldn't make it particularly efficient, but I doubt you'd notice unless your array was extremely large. Also you'd be limited to only being able to only find the max size for that particular array which isn't great. I'd stick with the sensible option.

Comment: **Compiler** will optimize your loop. Your job is to write readable code. Its job is to make it fast. Especially in such trivial cases. Probably your insane implementation is even slower, see for another case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9601625/1207195

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's compile them and see what we get!

First of all, AFAIK, there is no "max" function/macro defined in the C standard. So I added one (which looks convoluted because it avoids double evaluation of its inputs).

```
#define max(a,b) ({ \
    const __typeof__ (a) _a = (a); \
    const __typeof__ (b) _b = (b); \
    _a > _b ? _a : _b; \
})

int __attribute__ ((noinline)) test1(const int* array) {
    int largest = array[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
      const int val = array[i];
      if (val > largest) {
        largest = val;
      }
    }
    return largest;
}

int __attribute__ ((noinline)) test2(const int* array) {
    const int max_value =
      max(
        max(
          max(
            max(array[0], array[1]),
            max(array[2], array[3])),
          max(
            max(array[4], array[5]),
            max(array[6], array[7]))),
        max(
          max(
            max(array[8], array[9]),
            max(array[10], array[11])),
          max(
            max(array[12], array[13]),
            max(array[14], array[15]))));
    return max_value;
}
```

My gcc version, which is relevant when speaking about optimizations:

```
tmp$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

`-O2` for optimizations, `-S` to output assembly, `-o -` to output to stdout.

```
tmp$ gcc -std=c99 -O2 -S test.c -o -
    .file   "test.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  test1
    .type   test1, @function
test1:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    .p2align 4,,10
    .p2align 3
.L3:
    movl    4(%rdi,%rdx), %ecx
    cmpl    %ecx, %eax
    cmovl   %ecx, %eax
    addq    $4, %rdx
    cmpq    $60, %rdx
    jne .L3
    rep ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   test1, .-test1
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  test2
    .type   test2, @function
test2:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %edx
    cmpl    %edx, 4(%rdi)
    cmovge  4(%rdi), %edx
    movl    8(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    12(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    16(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    20(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    24(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    28(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    32(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    36(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    40(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    44(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    48(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    52(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    56(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovl   %eax, %edx
    movl    60(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    cmovge  %edx, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
    .size   test2, .-test2
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Okay, so `test2()` certainly looks much longer. However, it doesn't branch at all. And it's only ~3 instructions (memory load, comparison, conditional move) per element. `test1()` has 6 instructions (memory load, comparison, conditional move, loop counter increment, loop counter comparison, conditional branch). Lots of branches in `test1`, which can be bothersome (depending on how good your architecture's branch prediction is). On the other hand, `test2` increases code size, which will necessarily push something else out of instruction cache. And there are lots of data hazards in `test2` (well, and `test1`...) -- maybe we could rewrite it to use a few extra registers to reduce the number of pipeline stalls?

So, as you can probably see by now, this is not an easy question to answer.

The only real way to know is to measure it. And even then, it'll vary depending on internal implementation/optimizations/cache size of each CPU model.

So I wrote a small benchmark:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define N (1000000)

int main() {
    printf("    %12s %12s  %12s %12s\n", "test1 time", "test2 time", "test1 out", "test2 out");
    int* data = malloc(N * 16 * sizeof(int));
    srand(1);
    for (int i=0; i<16*N; ++i) {
        data[i] = rand();
    }

    const int* a;
    struct timespec t1, t2, t3;
    for (int attempt=0; attempt<10; ++attempt) {
        uint32_t sum1 = 0;
        uint32_t sum2 = 0;

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t1);
        a = data;
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
            sum1 += test1(a);
            a += 16;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t2);
        a = data;
        for (int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
            sum2 += test2(a);
            a += 16;
        }

        clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &t3);
        uint64_t nanos1 = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) * 1000000000L + (t2.tv_nsec - t1.tv_nsec);
        uint64_t nanos2 = (t3.tv_sec - t2.tv_sec) * 1000000000L + (t3.tv_nsec - t2.tv_nsec);
        printf("%2d: %12lu %12lu  %12u %12u\n", attempt+1, nanos1, nanos2, sum1, sum2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And the results:

```
tmp$ gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 test.c -o test
tmp$ ./test 
      test1 time   test2 time     test1 out    test2 out
 1:     16251659     10431322    4190722540   4190722540
 2:     16796884     10639081    4190722540   4190722540
 3:     16443265     10314624    4190722540   4190722540
 4:     17194795     10337678    4190722540   4190722540
 5:     16966405     10380047    4190722540   4190722540
 6:     16803840     10556222    4190722540   4190722540
 7:     16795989     10871508    4190722540   4190722540
 8:     16389862     11511950    4190722540   4190722540
 9:     16304850     11704787    4190722540   4190722540
10:     16309371     11269446    4190722540   4190722540
tmp$ gcc -std=gnu99 -O3 test.c -o test
tmp$ ./test 
      test1 time   test2 time     test1 out    test2 out
 1:      9090364      8813462    4190722540   4190722540
 2:      8745093      9394730    4190722540   4190722540
 3:      8942015      9839356    4190722540   4190722540
 4:      8849960      8834056    4190722540   4190722540
 5:      9567597      9195950    4190722540   4190722540
 6:      9130245      9115883    4190722540   4190722540
 7:      9680596      8930225    4190722540   4190722540
 8:      9268440      9998824    4190722540   4190722540
 9:      8851503      8960392    4190722540   4190722540
10:      9767021      8875165    4190722540   4190722540
tmp$ gcc -std=gnu99 -Os test.c -o test
tmp$ ./test 
      test1 time   test2 time     test1 out    test2 out
 1:     17569606     10447512    4190722540   4190722540
 2:     17755450     10811861    4190722540   4190722540
 3:     17718714     10372411    4190722540   4190722540
 4:     17743248     10378728    4190722540   4190722540
 5:     18747440     10306748    4190722540   4190722540
 6:     17877105     10782263    4190722540   4190722540
 7:     17787171     10522498    4190722540   4190722540
 8:     17771172     10445461    4190722540   4190722540
 9:     17683935     10430900    4190722540   4190722540
10:     17670540     10543926    4190722540   4190722540
tmp$ gcc -std=gnu99 -O2 -funroll-loops test.c -o test
tmp$ ./test 
      test1 time   test2 time     test1 out    test2 out
 1:      9840366     10008656    4190722540   4190722540
 2:      9826522     10529205    4190722540   4190722540
 3:     10208039     10363219    4190722540   4190722540
 4:      9863467     10284608    4190722540   4190722540
 5:     10473329     10054511    4190722540   4190722540
 6:     10298968     10520570    4190722540   4190722540
 7:      9846157     10595723    4190722540   4190722540
 8:     10340026     10041021    4190722540   4190722540
 9:     10434750     10404669    4190722540   4190722540
10:      9982403     10592842    4190722540   4190722540
```

Conclusion: the max() version is faster *on my Intel Core i7-3517U with 4 MB cache* (and I wouldn't claim any more than that because, again, the results may vary with microarchitecture).

Also, `-funroll-loops` or the extra-aggressive (and less safe) optimizations enabled by `-O3` really make a huge difference for the `test1` case, essentially making it equal in time to `test2` -- perhaps even slightly better with `-funroll-loops`, but close enough that we can't draw a confident conclusion from the numbers I got. It would probably be interesting to look at the assembly for `test1` there, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. ;)

So, I guess the answer is "it depends".

Comment: But as others have pointed out, `test1` is easier to read, so you should probably use that until you can *verify* that this comparison is actually critical to your program's performance. Readable/flexible code is better than saving a few milliseconds, if those milliseconds are in a part of the program that really doesn't matter anyway. :)

Comment: For someone who claims that *there is no "max" function/macro defined in the C standard.*, it looks odd to use non-standard constructs such as `typeof` and statement expressions to implement `max()`.

Comment: In my opinion to check loop performance with `-O2` (then **without loop unrolling**) is pretty _strange_. You should, at least, also include `-funroll-loops`.

Comment: `-funroll-loops` would probably help for the loop case, yes. However, this part of the gcc manual is important: "This option makes code larger, and may or may not make it run faster". Of course, for this simple loop, it will most likely be a big benefit. For others, maybe not. But honestly, I just didn't think of it. Will edit to add a run with that flag. :)

Answer (score 2):

Obviously the first one, it's more readable and robust.
Maybe `max()` is not implemented  in hardware.

Hare's a [implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) of max in c++

```
template <class T> const T& max (const T& a, const T& b) {
    return (a<b)?b:a;     // or: return comp(a,b)?b:a; for version (2)
}
```

And gcc-4.9.2 implementation of C [max](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Typeof.html#Typeof) define as

```
#define max(a,b) \
   ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
       typeof (b) _b = (b); \
     _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

So, it's better to use first one. Although size less than 3 may be consider to implement with second one.

Comment: `typeof` is not part of the standard C language.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is clearly the most straightforward implementation.

Nonetheless, this problem is related to the concept of [Sorting Networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network), which is a surprisingly complex theory on sorting fixed-size sets of data.

Comment: And, yes, `max` is implemented in hardware, usually in the form of a `cmp` instruction in `x86` and compatible processors :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, there is no max or min function in the C or GNU standard libraries.
The first one would be better to use.
Also, you can directly compare array[i] to present maximum.

```
int largest = array[0];
for (int i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
    if (array[i]>largest)
        largest=array[i];  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this function:

```
int max_array(int a[], int count) {
   int i,
    max = a[0];

   for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {
     if (a[i] > max) {
        max = a[i];
     }
   }

   return max;
}
```

Edit:

Sorry, have not saw that you tried that out. But anyway - this is the better implementation, the second one you proposed is just monstrous. I think if you want to keep your code clean, this is as far as you go.

Comment: How this is different from OP's _"sensible implementation"_ one ?

Comment: @P0W I am sorry, I did not notice that, check my edit.