# Intel modular arithmetic using AVX or SSE

Tags: sse, avx, modular-arithmetic

Is it possible to do modular arithmetic on integers with AVX or SSE?  i.e. perform several mods all at once.

Bipman

Comment: Yes but it's annoying, except in special cases. Do you have some more details?

Comment: Yes, it's for speeding up one pad encryption.

Comment: OTP? Isn't that just a XOR with a huge key?

Comment: It can be but I wondered if it could be done on several say words at once.

Comment: With XOR, trivially. I still don't get where the modular arithmetic comes in though.

Comment: For what I am doing, mod arithmetic on several words at once would be good, if not then I'll do it conventionally.

Comment: OK then the question is still, do you have more details - not a high level purpose, but specifically what operation are you executing. A general modulo operation is annoying, so it's important to know whether you're in any of the special cases.

Comment: Forget mod arithmetic, I meant xor as per your message.  x is the byte in the key (same length as file) and y is the byte from the message so x xor y produces z the encrypted byte.  If several xor processes could be done at once it would save time with large files.

Comment: In GCC and Clang you can just write a normal loop with byte-by-byte XORs and it will be vectorized automatically

Comment: OK, thanks.  Using assembler though.

Comment: Ok well use `pxor`  or `vpxor`, do you know how to do the rest? It's basically like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9603039/555045) but XOR instead of ADD.

Comment: Yep, that code looks good thanks.

Comment: Is the actual question still relevant? If so, clarify if what you need (e.g., is the divisor a compile-time constant?)