# How can I convert a number to text in Perl?

Tags: perl, numbers

I need some code in my program which takes a number as input and converts it into corresponding text e.g. 745 to "seven hundred forty five".

Now, I can write code for this, but is there any library or existing code I can use?

Comment: Working on a Euler Project problem, ye?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words

Comment: Helpful (Raku)? https://github.com/thundergnat/Lingua-EN-Numbers

Answer (score 18):

From perldoc of [Lingua::EN::Numbers](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Lingua::EN::Numbers):

```
use Lingua::EN::Numbers qw(num2en num2en_ordinal);

my $x = 234;
my $y = 54;
print "You have ", num2en($x), " things to do today!\n";
print "You will stop caring after the ", num2en_ordinal($y), ".\n";
```

prints:

```
You have two hundred and thirty-four things to do today!
You will stop caring after the fifty-fourth.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words)

From the above-mentioned link:

```
perl -MNumber::Spell -e 'print spell_number(2);'
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Math::BigInt::Named](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math::BigInt::Named::English) module.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %numinwrd = (
  0 => 'Zero', 1 => 'One', 2 => 'Two',   3 => 'Three', 4 => 'Four',
  5 => 'Five', 6 => 'Six', 7 => 'Seven', 8 => 'Eight', 9 => 'Nine',
);

print "The number when converted to words is 745=>".numtowrd(745)."\n";

sub numtowrd {
  my $num = shift;
  my $txt = "";  
  my @val = $num =~ m/./g;

  foreach my $digit (@val) {    
    $txt .= $numinwrd{$digit} . " ";   
  }

  return $txt;
}
```

The output is:

```
The number when converted to words is 745=>Seven Four Five
```

Comment: To convert `@val` to `$txt`, it might be easier to do `$txt = join " ", map {$numinwrd{$_}} @val`, effectively making your sub a one-liner. Also, this solution doesn't produce `seven hundred forty five`.

Comment: You can give the code if you can make the output to seven hundred forty five

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [Nums2Words](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Nums2Words).