# C# Money numeric value to written value

Tags: c#, currency

I am receiving data which I am basically recreating the image of a check for filing purposes. I have the monetary amount of the check coming in, but I need to create the written out value.

i.e $2400.22 >> Two Thousand Four Hundred Dollars and Twenty Two Cents

Was wondering if any one out there knows of a pre-packaged class or something so I don't have to rewrite the wheel.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at BenAlabasters [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776) in this [code golf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776) question for an idea of how to do this.

Comment: Vastly superior to the CodeProject one.

Answer (score 0):

It's not hard to write, but a quick search turns up [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/codesamples.aspx) CodeProject article, for example.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like this one. it's limited to doing check dollar amounts as it is but could be tweaked to work in a more general way.

```
    public static string ToWrittenValueString(this decimal number)
    {
        // convert the number to a usable value
        var numStr = Math.Round(number,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        // seperate the value before and after the decimal point
        var numParts = numStr.Split('.');

        IList<string> txt = new List<string>();

        // get the total number of digits in the number before the decimal point.
        var digits = numParts[0].Length;

        for (int n = 1; n <= digits; n++)
        {
            //this handles the hundreds, hundred thousands and hundred millions place
            if (n % 3 == 0)
            {
                txt.Add("HUNDRED");
                txt.Add(onesAndTeens[int.Parse(numParts[0][digits - n].ToString())]);

            }
            // this handles the two digits preceding the hundreds, hundred thousands and hundred millions place    
            if (n % 3 == 2 | (n == digits & n % 3!=0)) 
            {
                // this get's the integer equivilent of only those two digits
                var tmpnum = int.Parse(string.Join("", numParts[0].Skip(digits-n).Take(n % 3 == 2? 2: 1)));


                // this get's the name of the three didget grouping that the current digit's of interest are in i.e. thousand, million etc...  
                txt.Add(digitGroupName[((n - n % 3) / 3)]);
                // if the integer equivilent is less than 20 we use the onesAndTeens lookup table
                // if the integer equivilent is twenty or more we use the tens lookup for the most significant digit and the onesAndTeens lookup for the least significant digit
                if (tmpnum < 20)
                    txt.Add(onesAndTeens[tmpnum]); 
                else
                    txt.Add(string.Format("{0}{1}", tens[(tmpnum - tmpnum % 10) / 10], onesAndTeens[tmpnum % 10] ));
            }

        }

        return  string.Format("{0} AND {1}/100 DOLLARS", string.Join(" ", txt.Reverse()), numParts[1]);;
    }

    private static string[] onesAndTeens = new string[20] { "", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT","NINE","TEN","ELEVEN","TWELVE", "THIRTEEN","FOURTEEN","FIFTEEN","SIXTEEN","SEVENTEEN","EIGHTEEN","NINETEEN"};
    private static string[] tens = new string[10] {"","","TWENTY","THIRTY","FOURTY","FIFTY","SIXTY","SEVENTY","EIGHTY","NINETY"};
    private static string[] digitGroupName = new string[4] {"","THOUSAND","MILLION","BILLION" };
```