# Looking for a Numbert to Text library

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to convert numbers to their text form, I did this a while ago but I believe there should be a good library for this.

example

```
123 = "One Hundred Twenty Three"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [code golf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776) might be of some use.

Comment: I did search for Number to Test, never thought on Number to WORDS... thanks