# How to format the date into words

Tags: java

I am trying to convert java.util.Date into string as "Twenty Sixth of October Nineteen Ninety Three" for the date 26-10-1993.

How to do this in a generic fashion?

Comment: How do you want to convert `2009`? "twenty o nine"? "two thousand and nine"? What about `2010`?

Comment: 2009 as two thousand and nine 
2010 as two thousand and ten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the 3 parts of the date (the day, the month, the year), and just convert each respectively.

For the day, you're going to need a number to words converter. You can get a rather general one, or alternatively, since your numeric range is limited, you can write a simpler one that only works for the day range.

For the month, just map it to the month name. This should be straightforward.

For the year, you're going to have to be more specific on what the requirement is. Is `2010` "twenty ten"? What about `2009`? In any case, for `y=19xx`, `18xx`, etc, you can convert `y % 100` and `y / 100` to words and concatenate them.

This is because when `y=1234`, `y / 100 = 12` and `y % 100 = 34`. The `/` is the integer division in this context, and `%` is the remainder operator. Make sure to handle all the special cases, e.g. when `y % 100 == 0`, e.g. `1800` should be `eighteen hundred`, `1907` should (perhaps) be `nineteen o seven`, etc.

#### Related questions

- [Code Golf: Number to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words)