# Is there a built-in number to word converter in .NET?

Tags: .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert an integer into its verbal representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554314/how-can-i-convert-an-integer-into-its-verbal-representation)

Is there a built-in number to word converter in .NET? For example, 5 would become "Five" if the current culture is English.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/408776/102937

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=convert+dollars+to+words+c%23