# Changing float with decimal point into words

Tags: python-3.x, cpu-word, decimal-point

How do I change an input float (for example 50300.45) into words in the form of a voucher (fifty thousand three hundred and 45/100 dollars) in python?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I think it might be worthwhile you reading it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019

Answer (score 0):

To spell out money represented as a decimal string with two digits after the point: spell out the integer part, spell out the fraction:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import inflect # $ pip install inflect

def int2words(n, p=inflect.engine()):
    return ' '.join(p.number_to_words(n, wantlist=True, andword=' '))

def dollars2words(f):
    d, dot, cents = f.partition('.')
    return "{dollars}{cents} dollars".format(
        dollars=int2words(int(d)),
        cents=" and {}/100".format(cents) if cents and int(cents) else '')

for dollars in ['50300.45', '100', '00.00']:
    print(dollars2words(dollars))
```

#### Output

```
fifty thousand three hundred and 45/100 dollars
one hundred dollars
zero dollars
```

Here's [`inflect` module helps to convert integer to English words](https://github.com/pwdyson/inflect.py). See [How do I tell Python to convert integers into words](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8982163/4279)