# How to convert an integer number to words in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Write a function that takes an integer as input argument and returns
>   the integer using words.  For example if the input is 4721 then the
>   function should return the string "four seven two one".  Note that
>   there should be only one space between the words and they should be
>   all lowercased in the string that you return.

this is my code:

```
def Numbers_To_Words (number):
    dict = {1: "one", 2: "two", 3: "three", 4: "four", 5: "five", 6: "six", 7: "seven", 8: "eight", 9: "nine", 0: "zero"}
    output_str = " "
    list = []

#Main Program
number = 4721
result = Numbers_To_Words (number)
print (result)
```

My question is, How do I separate the numbers and then compare with the dictionary I have created? I know length doesn't work on integer data type. I know the further logic that is to send keys to the dictionary and obtain their respective value. But before that I am stuck here in separating digits of an integer number.

Comment: can't you convert the integer to a string (str(number)) ?
In that case you will also need to change dict to map characters to words!

Comment: I will try and implement this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use modules for it:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/num2words

Also, check similar questions: [How do I tell Python to convert integers into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words)

You can install the modules and see how it is implemented there.

But your problem is solved like:

```
def numbers_to_words (number):
    number2word = {'1': "one", '2': "two", '3': "three", '4': "four", '5': "five", '6': "six",
            '7': "seven", '8': "eight", '9': "nine", '0': "zero"}
    return " ".join(map(lambda i: number2word[i], str(number)))


print(numbers_to_words(1234))
```

Comment: It is obviously a homework assignment so this answer isn't helpful at all

Answer (score 6):

There is a way that is simpler than the rest:

```
def number_to_words(number)
    words = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"]
    return " ".join(words[int(i)] for i in str(number))
```

Comment: ... or `return " ".join(words[int(digit)] for digit in str(number))` - which I find easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

```
def number_to_words(number):
    dict={"1":"one","2":"two","3":"three","4":"four","5":"five","6":"six","7":"seven","8":"eight","9":"nine","0":"zero"}
    s=""
    for c in str(number):
        s+=dict[c]+" "
    #if it's matter that the string won't conatain
    #space at the end then add the next line:
    s=s[:-1]

    return s
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you where you can't import modules for converting numbers to words. This code is for converting numbers from 1 to 1000 both inclusive.

```
def integer_to_english(number):
    if number>=1 and number<=1000:
        a = ['','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine','ten','eleven','twelve','thirteen','fourteen','fifteen','sixteen','seventeen','eighteen','nineteen','twenty ','thirty ','fourty ','fifty ','sixty ','seventy ','eighty ','ninty ']
        if number<=20:
            if number%10==0: return a[number]
            else: return a[number]
        elif number<100:
            b=number-20
            r=b%10
            b//=10
            return a[20+b]+a[r]
        elif number<1000:
            if number%100==0:
                b=number//100
                return a[b]+' hundred'
            else:
                r=number%100
                b=number//100
                if r<=20:
                    return a[b]+' hundred'+' and '+a[r]
                else:
                    r=r-20
                    d=r//10
                    r%=10
                    return a[b]+' hundred'+' and '+a[20+d]+a[r]
        elif number==1000:
            return 'one thousand'
        else:
            return -1

number=789
print(integer_to_english(number))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `re.sub`

```
>>> def Numbers_To_Words (number):
    dict_ = {'1': "one", '2': "two", '3': "three", '4': "four", '5': "five", '6': "six", '7': "seven", '8': "eight", '9': "nine", '0': "zero"}
    return re.sub(r'\d', lambda m: dict_[m.group()] + ' ', str(number)).strip()

>>> print Numbers_To_Words(4721)
four seven two one
>>> print Numbers_To_Words(98765423)
nine eight seven six five four two three
```

Comment: Yeah, to hell with "Readability counts".

Comment: Regex seems to be overkill in this case.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus ok, which solution you prefer? May I tell you the drawbacks on that?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: [zondo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35795757/3821804) is my favorite, [JRazors'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35794203/3821804) is 2nd best. If you want to filter digits, pipe it through `filter(str.isdigit)` before `map` / add `if i.isdigit()` clause to generator expression. Does it have any drawback?

Answer (score 0):

```
def number_to_words(number):
    names = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
    lst = []
    while True:
        lst.insert(0, number % 10) # Prepend
        number /= 10
        if number == 0:    # Do this here rather than in the while condition
           break;          # so that 0 results in ["zero"]

    # If you want a list, then:
    return lst;

    # If you want a string, then:
    return " ".join(lst)
```

Comment: Prepending to Python list is slow. Probably faster would be appending, and then reversing.

Comment: That was actually my initial reaction :-), but I decided that speed is unlikely to be important here - whereas readability is.  (Oh, and thanks for the edit.  Correctness is even more important!)

Answer (score 0):

```py
num_words={ 
    
    '0':'Zero',
    '1':'One',
    '2':'Two',
    '3':'Three',
    '4':'Four',
    '5':'Five',
    '6':'Six',
    '7':'Seven',
    '8':'Eight',
    '9':'Nine',
    '10':'Ten',
    
    '11':'Eleven',
    '12':'Twelve',
    '13':'Thirteen',
    '14':'Fourteen',
    '15':'Fifteen',
    '16':'Sixteen',
    '17':'Seventeen',
    '18':'Eighteen',
    '19':'Nineteen',
    
    '20':'Twenty',
    '30':'Thirty',
    '40':'Fourty',
    '50':'Fifty',
    '60':'Sixty',
    '70':'Seventy',
    '80':'Eighty',
    '90':'Ninety',
 
    }
    
def num_2_words(num):
    
    
    if num <= 20: return num_words[str(num)]
    elif num % 10 == 0 and num < 100: return num_words[str(num)]
    elif num < 100: return num_words[str(num//10)+'0']+' '+num_words[str(num%10)]
    elif num % 100 == 0 and num < 1000: return  num_words[str(num//100)]+' '+'Hundred'
    elif num < 1000: return num_words[str(num//100)]+' Hundred and '+ num_2_words(num%100)
    elif num % 1000 == 0 and num < 10000: return num_words[str(num//1000)]+' '+'Thousand'
    elif num < 10000: return num_words[str(num//1000)]+' Thousand '+ num_2_words(num%1000)
    elif num == 10000: return 'Ten Thousand'
    else: return 'more than Ten Thousand'
    
    
while True:  
    num=int(input('enter the number: '))
    print(num_2_words(num))
```