# How to convert number to words

Tags: python

I'm beginner, i have homework that requires the user to input a number and it convert it to words.For example:

```
15342
```

to

```
one five three four two
```

this's my code, but it only work with a number:

```
def convert_text():
    arr = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine']   
    word = arr[n]
    return word
n =int(input())
print(convert_text())
```

I am not allowed to use the num2word library and dictionary.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an integer number to words in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794173/how-to-convert-an-integer-number-to-words-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794173/how-to-convert-an-integer-number-to-words-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the value you pas being a string, then you can iterate over its chars

```
arr = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']

def convert_text(value):
    result = []
    for char in value:
        result.append(arr[int(char)])
    return " ".join(result)

print(convert_text("1625"))  # one six two five
print(convert_text("98322"))  # nine eight three two two

n = input()
print(convert_text(n))
```

Or just with generator syntax

```
def convert_text(value):
    return " ".join(arr[int(char)] for char in value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code hope this can help you

```
def convert_text(n):
    word = ""
    arr = ['zero','one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine'] 
    ''' Convert to string n from input for iterate over each single unit'''
    for value in str(n):
       ''' Convert back unit of string into number '''
       num = int(value);
       ''' Add new word to previous words '''
       word = word + " " + arr[num]
    return word
n = int(input())
print(convert_text(n))
```