# Using a or an correctly in a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x

Imagine a dice roller where you want to print the result with good grammar.

- `'You rolled a 18'` is an example of bad grammar.
- `'You rolled an 18'` is an example of good grammar.
- `'You rolled an 5'` would be bad grammar.

I could define a function that does a pile of `if` statements but that doesn't seem Pythonic.

```
#ideally something like this 
print(f'You rolled {a-or-an} {someint}')
```

Comment: Natural language isn't simple. You need to create some sort of mapping between numbers and the article to use based on the initial sound in the name of the number. That could be a function or a `dict`, but you need to define it yourself.

Comment: You only need one if statement: `if someint < 10: a-or-an = 'a'`

Comment: @Max "You rolled an 7"?

Comment: @chepner wrong way

Comment: @Max It's not the size of the number that is the issue: it's the *sound* the name of the number starts with. You wouldn't say "You rolled an 15".

Comment: For a general solution you can convert the roll [integer into a word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982414/5858851) and then check if that word starts with a vowel. However, if  you knew the max and min rolls allowed you can enumerate the ones that require `"an"` and have a special case for them.

Comment: @chepner my bad, i stopped at `11` and assumed true for rest

Comment: @pault Even that doesn't quite work: "You rolled a 100", not "You rolled an 100". (Assuming you say "one hundred", not "hundred".)

Comment: @chepner special case for in the first word is `"one"` (you wouldn't say "You rolled an 1" either)

Comment: Vocal experimentation suggests you only need an `'an'` when the number in word form begins with an `'ei'`

Comment: @Max so maybe `print("You rolled %s %d" % ("an" if someint == 18 or str(someint)[0] == '8' else "a", someint))`

Comment: My condition is still true, if you examine it word form, if the word begins with 'ei' like 'eighteen' or 'eighty' it works, it doesnt work just looking at the integers

Comment: Omitting the article would also be grammatical: You rolled 11. You rolled 12.

Comment: For the benefit of those coming here to find software to generate a or an, correct except for rare cases, given the following word as a string, a comprehensive solution in 116 lines is at https://github.com/Kaivosukeltaja/php-indefinite-article . This was a port of a Python function to do the same thing. All the various cases are clearly presenting in this function, so you can extract only what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191585/using-a-or-an-correctly-in-a-sentence#comment99008242_56191585) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56191585/using-a-or-an-correctly-in-a-sentence#comment99008299_56191585), I think the following would work for you:

```
def getDiceRollString(someint):
    a_or_an = "an" if someint in (11, 18) or str(someint)[0] == '8' else "a"
    return "You rolled %s %d" % (a_or_an, someint)
```

You can try it out:

```
for i in [1, 5, 8, 11, 15, 18, 28, 81, 88, 800]:
    print(getDiceRollString(i))
#You rolled a 1
#You rolled a 5
#You rolled an 8
#You rolled an 11
#You rolled a 15
#You rolled an 18
#You rolled a 28
#You rolled an 81
#You rolled an 88
#You rolled an 800
```

Comment: I'd say that this most elegant, I'd also like to think that I contributed to this answer aha.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `num2word` (installed by `pip install num2word`)

```
import num2word
a-or-an ='an' if numtoword.to_card(someint)[0] == 'e' else 'a'
```

Unfortunately because its based on sounds, and sounds are based on words, I don't think there is a way of doing this by examining integers thus the solution isn't very pythonic.

Also feel free to disprove this (as I don't know)

Previous was disproved in the comments below by `11`, this should now be fixed.

Comment: `numtoword.to_card(11) == "eleven"`, I assume.

Comment: Not all numbers start with e or a. Two, thirty, five, six, nine...

Comment: @DavidSpector youre misunderstanding the if statement and the point of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my un-optimized idea. Going off of the other answers and converting to English, then changing the article (a/an) based on the first letter, if it's a vowel. Except for `o` in `one` because the word `one` actually sounds like `won` where there is a consonant `w` as the first sound.

Anywho, here's my idea.

```
from random import randint

import inflect # python -m pip install inflect

p = inflect.engine()

numlist = [1,7,8,10,11,12,11000000]

#for i in range(0, 10):
for i in numlist:
    article = 'a'
    num = i #randint(0, 10000000000)
    numword = p.number_to_words(num)
    if numword[:1] in 'aeiu':
        article = 'an'

    print("You rolled ", article, " ", num, " (", numword, ")", sep='')
```