# How can i generate a sequence of numbers as text in python

Tags: python, numpy

I need to generate a sequence of numbres, for example from `1 to 100` (this number could be much greater) in an array but as text like

```
[
    'one',
    'two',
    'three',
    ...
    'one hundred',
]
```

is there a library that do this? or i have to do it manually? and if there is a way to do it in spanish will be a plus.

Comment: Your answer can be found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026089/12881604

Comment: maybe you could check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words

Comment: i will try the one with inflect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This might help you but in order to do it in spanish you need to understand the code and change the code a little
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-number-to-words/

EDIT:
I think this will help you more there are multiple languages supported in this module
https://pypi.org/project/num2words/

Comment: this might work, it do the spanish translation already, will try.

Answer (score 0):

use inflect:

```
>>>import inflect
>>>p = inflect.engine()
>>>p.number_to_words(1234)
u'one thousand, two hundred and thirty-four'
```

Comment: will try this one

Answer (score -3):

You have to do it manually just use replace.