# how can i convert from number data type to words (string data type)

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, numbers

Can python convert number to string data type ?
ex: i input "35" => result: thirty five

```
number = 35
print("number with string type: ")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Python to convert integers into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words)

Comment: try `str(number)`

Comment: Try it by yourself, first. And if you stuck somewhere, then ask about that! Or using library is good method as mentioned by Arnaud.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `inflect`. You can install `inflect` through pip. Try `pip install inflect` in CMD or install through your IDE.
Try below code,

```
import inflect
print(inflect.engine().number_to_words(35))
```

Comment: You can install `inflect` through pip. Try `pip install inflect` in CMD or install through your IDE.

Comment: Done! Edited the answer with this detail!

Answer (score -1):

you can use num2words for this task like this.

from num2words import num2words

result = num2words(35)

thirty five

Comment: OP wants from `35` to `thirty five`.

Comment: not like this, i want it become a word, like ex i've post

Comment: oh my mistake, here is the correct way. you can use num2words for this task  like this.   
from num2words import num2words 
result =  num2words(35)
-->>  thirty five

Comment: You should update your answer rather than post the code in the comment section

Comment: hey, i updated my answer. please check