# convert number to alphabet python?

Tags: python, math, numbers, alphabetical

Write a program that receives a number and displays the letter equivalent of that number. Write the program so that for
Nomadillion (usable. For negative numbers, write the word "negative" first) such as negative one (. �� to �� �� numbers from ��−
Use the small-scale (American) mode to name large numbers.
And ... use to name numbers

Comment: There is no "*letter equivalent of [a] number*", only conventions. You need to be more explicit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Python to convert integers into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words)

Comment: @amirhosseinzadeh What do you mean by Nomadillion? I could not understand the last 2 sentences, maybe you can clarify those.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 libraries for this usecase: inflect and num2word.
Try these examples, from there you can extend the program to include negative formatting.

```
>>>import inflect
>>>p = inflect.engine()
>>>p.number_to_words(99)
ninety-nine

>>> import num2word
>>> num2word.to_card(15)
'fifteen'
>>> num2word.to_card(55)
'fifty-five'
>>> num2word.to_card(1555)
'one thousand, five hundred and fifty-five'
```