# Text version of an integer (1 -> one, et c) in Python

Tags: python, number-formatting

Is there a way to get the text equivalent of a number in Python? I've added a little script as a suggested answer, but I don't know if there should be commata or hyphens in it. I was hoping for a standard library version, like there is for, say, month names.

Comment: Have you checked num2words? https://pypi.org/project/num2words/

Comment: Does this is answer for this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words

Comment: I think my real struggle was finding search terms to locate an answer. Any combination of integer, name, convert, text, string, written version... that all refers to stuff you do more often.

Comment: @sr-s num2words looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```py
class NumberNamer:
    # try to reproduce num2words as adding that library isn't a fight I want to have https://pypi.org/project/num2words/
    single_digit_names = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine', ]
    teen_names = ['ten', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'thirteen', None, 'fifteen', ]
    tens_label = {2: 'twenty', 3: 'thirty', 4: 'forty', 5: 'fifty', 6: 'sixty', 7: 'seventy', 8: 'eighty',
                  9: 'ninety'}
    power_labels = [(1, 'thousand'), (2, 'million'), (3, 'billion'), (4, 'trillion'), (5, 'quadrillion'),
                    (7, 'ERROR')]

    @classmethod
    def to_name(cls, val: int) -> str:
        """
        Convert a number to its name 1 -> one; 37 -> thirty-seven
        :param val: number
        :return:    name of number
        """
        if val < 0:
            return f"negative {cls.to_name(-val)}"
        td = int(val / 10) % 10
        od = val % 10
        ones = cls.single_digit_names[od]
        # interpret the tens digit
        if td == 0:
            tens = ones
        elif td == 1:
            if od != 4 and od < len(cls.teen_names):
                tens = cls.teen_names[od]
            elif od == 8:
                tens = f'{ones}een'
            else:
                tens = f'{ones}teen'
        else:
            tens = cls.tens_label[td]
            if od > 0:
                tens = f'{tens}-{ones}'
        if val < 100:
            return tens
        hd = int(val / 100) % 10
        name = f'{cls.to_name(hd)} hundred {tens}'
        for power, label in cls.power_labels:
            if val < pow(1000, power):
                return name
            digits = int(val / pow(1000, power)) % 1000
            name = f"{cls.to_name(digits)} {label}, {name}"
        raise Exception(f"{val} too big, concocted {name} and gave up")

nn = NumberNamer()
for xmpl in list(range(-20, 20)) + [37, 84, 295, 43823, 3438821, 95234098191, 458741684687387373,
                                    6473743453546436874374347354]:
    print(nn.to_name(xmpl))
```

Comment: Why does this need to be a class? Also please fix the indentation of the code

Comment: Seems like a couple of lists would save a whole lot of `if` / `elif`.