# Numbers converted to Word Numbers- Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert random numbers between 0 to 99 to a word without writing a line of script for each one individually? For example it takes 2 and turns it into "two". (without using any external libraries)

Comment: You can use *inflect* as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25026089/13778504).

Comment: Thank you for you help but I'm looking for a way without external libraries.

Comment: Without external libraries, the answer is no.

Comment: Find a list of the word equivalents online and then put it into a dictionary. You can use Python itself to add the keys (with a for loop), so it's just about finding the list online.