# How do I turn digits into texts in Python?

Tags: python

How do I create a function that returns digits into texts? For example, turning 33 into 'three three'.

My code so far:

```
table = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine",
    10: "ten"
}

def digits_to_text(s):
    return table.get(s)
```

this only works if it is a single digit to turn into text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I tell Python to convert integers into words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982163/how-do-i-tell-python-to-convert-integers-into-words)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the number into a string, split it into characters, convert each character, and combine them together into one string.

```py
table = {
    0: "zero",
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine"
}

def digits_to_text(s):
    output = []
    for char in str(s): # convert to string, and loop through each character
        output.append(table.get(int(char))) # convert character to word and add to the list
    return " ".join(output) # join the list together into a single string
```

Also, your dictionary was missing 0 and had 10, so I changed it in the example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Typecast the number to string.
2. Iterate across each character

   - While typecasting it back to integer for getting values from the dict.

> ```
> table = {
>     0: "zero",
>     1: "one",
>     2: "two",
>     3: "three",
>     4: "four",
>     5: "five",
>     6: "six",
>     7: "seven",
>     8: "eight",
>     9: "nine"
> }
>
> def digits_to_text(s):
>     return " ".join([table.get(int(i)) for i in str(s)])
> ```

Comment: The list comprehension is unnecessary. You can pass a generator expression to `str.join`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the letter of the problem, it does not seem the user does not need to map `0` to anything unless is preceded by a `1`, in which case it will be mapped to `ten`. I don't know if that is a mispecification of the problem or a genuine need. In the first case, solutions above address the objective pretty well.
Otherwise, we could take the following approach:

```
table = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    3: "three",
    4: "four",
    5: "five",
    6: "six",
    7: "seven",
    8: "eight",
    9: "nine",
    10: "ten"
}

def digits_to_letters(s, default= "-"):
    s = list(s)[::-1]
    res = []
    while len(s) > 0:
        l1 = s.pop()
        n1 = int(l1)
        c1 = table.get(n1, " ")
        if (n1 == 1) and (len(s) > 0):
            l2 = s.pop()
            n1n2 = int(l1 + l2)
            c1c2 = table.get(n1n2)
            if c1c2:
                res.append(c1c2)
            else:
                res.append(c1)
                res.append(table.get(int(l2), default))
        else:
            res.append(c1)
    return res
            
print(digits_to_letters("123102303231"))
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'ten', 'two', 'three', ' ', 'three', 'two', 'three', 'one']
```

As you can see, the forth and fifth characters - `10` - are mapped to `ten`, while the seventh and eighth - `30` - to `three` and   (there is the option to choose a different default character instead of an empty space).