# Convert string value to english word

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out / where to start in regards to this situation say for example 
I enter $127.45 in to a textbox 
I would expect the application to spit back 
one hundred and twenty-seven dollars and forty-five cents

The word will then be placed on a document and sent to the client.

I have found this solution which seemed promising [Code Golf: Number to Words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309884/code-golf-number-to-words/408776#408776) which filled me with some hope, unfortunately after trying that it only spits back 
one hundred and twenty seven

Would someone be able to give me a hand?

Comment: Split on `.` and process both tokens?

Comment: just an idea, why not split the 127.45 in two numbers, 127 and 45 and call the method twice?

Comment: This was a coding challenge at our company - its quite interesting, not difficult to do.

Comment: Showing some effort would be helpful in order to help you. Where did you get stuck when implementing the code of the other post?

Comment: As suggested above: split on `.`, process both parts, append dollars and cents, taking singular/plural into account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the decimal part of the number into a separate integer, then just call your number to words function twice something like this:

```
double value = 125.23;
int dollars = (int)value;
int cents = (int)((value - (int)value) * 100);
Console.WriteLine("{0} dollars and {1} cents", wordify(dollars), wordify(cents));
```